# T-SQL (varchar(max) vs CLR (string, SqlString, SqlChars)?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2005, types, sqlclr

I have a problem, that I can't solve. I'm using SQL Server 2005, C# CLR for using outer dll. The problem is at length of parameter. I need to use as function parameter type `varchar(max)`. If at C# code I use `string`, `SqlSring`, I can't use T-SQL type `varchar(max)`, just `varchar(4000)` of `nvarchar(4000)`. I need to say, that can be situations, when I need to use more then 4000 symbols, so I need know, what C# type I need to use for `varchar(max)`.

I have read a lot of articles, and several of them say, that for this I can use `SqlChars`. But! I have manipulations with strings. How can I have actions with `string` or `SqlString` and then convert to `SqlChars`? (It is possible `SqlChars.ToString()` or `SqlChars.ToSqlString()`).

I didn't find any C# code for this.

Comment: A `varchar(max)` string that's using its maximum capacity will not be loadable into a CLR string, since it will exhaust the address space. Can you be more explicit about what actions you want to perform against these strings?

Comment: I convert any SQL type to varchar and send this value to the outer dll. Than, do manipulations with it and return to SQL Server. Now I use SQL/vchar(4000) and C#/string. I need more than 4000 symbols.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I was under the impression both SQL Server's `varchar(max)` as well as a .NET `string` instance could be up to 2 GB in size....

Comment: @marc_s - as it turns out, a `varchar(max)` variable can [contain more than 2GB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7611394/15498). But I was mostly working from the other side. Certainly under 32 bit CLR, you can't actually allocate a 2GB object, and I think you can struggle even under 64 bit.

Answer (score 13):

What you need to do is add SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1) attribute to parameter:

```
[return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
public static SqlString YourSqlFunction([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]SqlString sourceSS)
{ return new }
```

Comment: Correct! This will cause VS to create correct script automatically!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer. Not just only me asked about this question. I have to read posts more attentively...

Can read here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlnetfx/thread/391ebb98-e1b5-47fc-a72d-9f1e39829e3a The problem of CLR compatibility solves not very difficult.

All time I wanted use `varchar(max)` and tried to use C# types `string`, `SqlString`, `SqlChars`. Need to use T-SQL `nvarchar(max)`, and you can use any of C# types `string`, `SqlString`, `SqlChars`!

Of course `nvarchar` taking up more space than `varchar` at two times.

Comment: SQLCLR does not allow for `VARCHAR`, whether it is 1 - 4000 or `MAX`. `NVARCHAR` is the only string type that the SQLCLR API passes through (well, I guess `object` / `SQL_VARIANT` can also pass a string of up to 4000). If you pass in `VARCHAR` values, they are implicitly converted to `NVARCHAR`. Please do not use, or suggest using, `string` as a SQLCLR input or output param type. For more info, please see my series, [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/), on SQL Server Central (free registration is required for that site).

Answer (score 0):

Try using length `-1`. Something like this:

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = "hdfiophdopigherog";
```

Comment: I can't try this, because I don't have SqlCommand... Just input parameter - manipulation with it - out parameter. And I need IN/OUT parameters will be SqlChars

Comment: While `-1` is technically correct, this answer is still irrelevant to the question. This answer is dealing with a SqlConnection API and not the SQLCLR API.