# Maximum size of a varchar(max) variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

At any time in the past, if someone had asked me the maximum size for a `varchar(max)`, I'd have said 2GB, or looked up a more exact [figure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) (2^31-1, or 2147483647).

However, in some recent testing, I discovered that `varchar(max)` variables can apparently exceed this size:

```
create table T (
    Val1 varchar(max) not null
)
go
declare @KMsg varchar(max) = REPLICATE('a',1024);
declare @MMsg varchar(max) = REPLICATE(@KMsg,1024);
declare @GMsg varchar(max) = REPLICATE(@MMsg,1024);
declare @GGMMsg varchar(max) = @GMsg + @GMsg + @MMsg;
select LEN(@GGMMsg)
insert into T(Val1) select @GGMMsg
select LEN(Val1) from T
```

Results:

```
(no column name)
2148532224
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 7119, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Attempting to grow LOB beyond maximum allowed size of 2147483647 bytes.
The statement has been terminated.

(no column name)
(0 row(s) affected)
```

So, given that I now know that a *variable* can exceed the 2GB barrier - does anyone know what the actual limit is for a `varchar(max)` variable?

---

(Above test completed on SQL Server 2008 (not R2). I'd be interested to know whether it applies to other versions)

Comment: `declare @x varchar(max) = 'XX'; SELECT LEN(REPLICATE(@x,2147483647))` gives `4294967294` for me but takes a long time to run - even after the `SELECT` has returned so not sure what that extra time is spent doing .

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980502/sql-varcharmax-vs-varcharfix

Comment: Paul White gives some details here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/315189/3690

Comment: @MartinSmith - thanks. Probably worth editing it into your answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no upper limit in 2008.

In SQL Server 2005 the code in your question fails on the assignment to the `@GGMMsg` variable with

> Attempting to grow LOB beyond maximum allowed size of 2,147,483,647
> bytes.

the code below fails with

> REPLICATE: The length of the result exceeds the length limit (2GB) of
> the target large type.

However it appears these limitations have quietly been lifted. On 2008

```
DECLARE @y VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),92681); 

SET @y = REPLICATE(@y,92681);

SELECT LEN(@y)
```

Returns

```
8589767761
```

I ran this on my 32 bit desktop machine so this 8GB string is way in excess of addressable memory

Running

```
select internal_objects_alloc_page_count
from sys.dm_db_task_space_usage
WHERE session_id = @@spid
```

Returned

```
internal_objects_alloc_page_co 
------------------------------ 
2144456
```

so I presume this all just gets stored in `LOB` pages in `tempdb` with no validation on length. The page count growth was all associated with the `SET @y = REPLICATE(@y,92681);` statement. The initial variable assignment to `@y` and the `LEN` calculation did not increase this.

The reason for mentioning this is because the page count is hugely more than I was expecting. Assuming an 8KB page then this works out at 16.36 GB which is obviously more or less double what would seem to be necessary. I speculate that this is likely due to the inefficiency of the string concatenation operation needing to copy the entire huge string and append a chunk on to the end rather than being able to add to the end of the existing string. Unfortunately at the moment the `.WRITE` method [isn't supported](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/525286/varchar-max-write-method-for-variables-in-update-statements) for varchar(max) variables.

[Paul White confirms the above supposition here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/315189/3690) and also provides the information that the variable is held entirely in memory if <= 512KB and changes to the tempdb-based backup scheme for values larger than that.

**Addition**

I've also tested the behaviour with concatenating `nvarchar(max) + nvarchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max) + varchar(max)`. Both of these allow the 2GB limit to be exceeded. Trying to then store the results of this in a table then fails however with the error message `Attempting to grow LOB beyond maximum allowed size of 2147483647 bytes.` again. The script for that is below (may take a long time to run).

```
DECLARE @y1 VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),2147483647); 
SET @y1 = @y1 + @y1;
SELECT LEN(@y1), DATALENGTH(@y1)  /*4294967294, 4294967292*/


DECLARE @y2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),1073741823); 
SET @y2 = @y2 + @y2;
SELECT LEN(@y2), DATALENGTH(@y2)  /*2147483646, 4294967292*/


DECLARE @y3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = @y2 + @y1
SELECT LEN(@y3), DATALENGTH(@y3)   /*6442450940, 12884901880*/

/*This attempt fails*/
SELECT @y1 y1, @y2 y2, @y3 y3
INTO Test
```

Comment: Excellent - so it would appear that the documentation is rather "incomplete" - I note that the usual page refers to a maximum "storage size", which presumably only applies to columns, not variables.

Comment: @Damien - Definitely appears that way. Not sure if there is some other limit that can be reached in terms of total number of pages but I think this is stored in a B tree structure (based on p.381 of SQL Server 2008 internals) so in principle could be extended definitely.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - [The documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345368.aspx) seems flat out wrong based on the experiments here, stating fairly unambiguously that "Large object (LOB) data type variables and parameters ... types can be up to 2 GB in size"

Comment: Kinda useless but interesting though. In theory you could fill the disk with one variable... :-)

Comment: I have some hesitation here because storing a value in a variable is not the same as storing it in a column. Do you feel like trying this with a column instead--or do you have an update? Even SQL Server 2000 could have `varchar` values longer than 8000 characters in literal strings in code, as long as you didn't try to put it in a variable or `varchar` column.

Comment: @ErikE - I did try that and it doesn't work. This only applies to variables. I mention that on trying to store the results of this in a table it failed with the error message `Attempting to grow LOB beyond maximum allowed size of 2147483647 bytes` on the `SELECT @y1 y1, @y2 y2, @y3 y3 INTO Test`

Comment: @Martin Sorry about missing that. You said it very clearly--"Trying to then store the results of this in a table then fails..." My fault for skimming too fast!

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT**: After further investigation, my original assumption that this was an anomaly (bug?) of the `declare @var datatype = value` syntax is incorrect.

I modified your script for 2005 since that syntax is not supported, then tried the modified version on 2008. In 2005, I get the `Attempting to grow LOB beyond maximum allowed size of 2147483647 bytes.` error message. In 2008, the modified script is still successful.

```
declare @KMsg varchar(max); set @KMsg = REPLICATE('a',1024);
declare @MMsg varchar(max); set @MMsg = REPLICATE(@KMsg,1024);
declare @GMsg varchar(max); set @GMsg = REPLICATE(@MMsg,1024);
declare @GGMMsg varchar(max); set @GGMMsg = @GMsg + @GMsg + @MMsg;
select LEN(@GGMMsg)
```

Comment: The script always produces an error (by trying to do the table insert), but on 2008, I always get one result in the first result set, indicating that the variable does exist, and is longer than 2^31-1 in length.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I cut the script down to just the variable portion and now get the same results as you. In 2005, I get the `Attempting to grow...` error on the `set @GGMMsg=...` statement. In 2008, the script is successful.