# Max size of a Varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

On SQL Server 2008 R2 (64 bit) what is the max size of a varchar(max)?

I know that after 8K it goes to an overflow page, but I don't know how many chars I can put in over all.

Comment: Did you look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)? 2^31 -1 *bytes"

Comment: @gbn - I did look at MSDN.  I think my confusion came from not being sure that one "char" = one byte.

Comment: nvarchar(max): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx No different tom, say char(100) vs nchar(100) = 100 bytes vs 200 bytes

Comment: `varchar(max)` [Variables seem to allow longer though](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7611394/73226)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the MAX types can accomodate 2GB of data. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Validating from .Net prior to calling SQL it will be `int.MaxValue`

```
Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue);
> 2147483647
```