# Truncated String Data error when inserting into an nvarchar(max) field

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a `SqlDataSource` and an `<asp:ListView>` setup to handle comments on another form, with the following textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="CommentTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comment") %>' Width="400px" Height="125px" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

The datasource has the following `InsertCommand` and `asp:Parameter` set on it:

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblSLS_SpecComments] ([SpecID], [Author], [Comment]) VALUES (@SpecID, @Author, @Comment)" 
  <asp:Parameter Name="SpecID" Type="Int32" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="Author" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="Comment" Type="String" />
```

When I try to insert a longer comment (an example would be 500 'f's), I get an error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

The column that I'm inserting into is of datatype `nvarchar(max)`, so it should be able to hold about a book's worth of characters, which is substantially fewer than I'm handing it.

Any clue about what's going on?

Comment: Can it be that you exceed the length of the Author column?

Comment: Shouldn't be.  Author is setup as nvarchar(50), and is being truncated in code behind to only be the username (verified this).

Comment: @Crimius - Use SQL Server Profiler to trace the query being executed. You can then see exactly what is happening. I would think Mr Mush is correct here :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check does your table have any trigger to another datatable, and the trigger tries insert/update the value into smaller field.

Answer (score 0):

`Nvarchar(Max)` can't be the source of that error. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611394/maximum-size-of-a-varcharmax-variable) question
Check other field like `Author` and use `MaxLenght` property of `texbox` where ever possible.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I tried to insert long values from the designer (Edit top 200 rows...) on a nvarchar(max) field.

When I ran the update manually from the query window it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a strange case with SQL Server 2008 where I could not insert into a nvarchar(max) column even if the query was not trying to insert anything at all (like Where 1 <> 1). The only solution that worked for me was **sp_updatestats**. Apparently, the server was thinking that the source column value could potentially be larger than nvarchar(max) (in fact it was nvarchar(20))