# Variable Length More Than 8000 Chars

Tags: sql-server

Variable Length More Than 8000 Chars

my variable length is exceeding 8000 characters. 
as we can't use text data type with a local variable and max limit for 
varchar data type is 8000 so what is the soln for that.

thanks,

Comment: What version of SQL server?

Comment: Need a bit more info about what you are trying to do. But a start would be ReadText and WriteText. Warning it's quite painful. Personally I'd have a serious think about finding something else to do the work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `VARCHAR(MAX)`. It stores a maximum of 2 147 483 647 characters.

Comment: More than that even, for a [variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611394/maximum-size-of-a-varcharmax-variable)

Comment: True. Thanks for interesting research.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `varchar(max)` data type

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nvarchar(max)` data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VARCHAR(MAX) or TEXT datatypes.But I prefer using VARCHAR(MAX) as TEXT datatype is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not text that you want to store, use

```
varbinary(max)
```