# When is nvarchar(Max) = nvarchar(4000)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nvarchar

There are multiple posts on both SO and other sites which clearly state that the maximum length of `nvarchar(max)` is 2GB. However, I see also much confusion in both internet and real life that it actually is 8000/4000 in Unicode.

I would like to know what things could change that fact, or maybe lead someone to falsely assume so.

Some suggestions/partial answers I've already gathered:

1. Are there older SQL Server versions which did only support a maximum of 4000?
2. When assigning `nvarchar(max)` variable/column to a concatenation of non-max-sized components, must we convert everything to `nvarchar(max)` explicitly? Here is something showcasing a strange example, where a text-returning function requires converting, whereas the N for the literal can be omitted:

   ```
   declare @s nvarchar(max) 
   select @s = convert(nvarchar(max), replicate('.', 8000)) + N'Hi!'
   select len(@s) -- returns 8003

   declare @s nvarchar(max) 
   select @s = replicate('.', 8000) + N'Hi!' 
   select len(@s) -- returns 4000

   declare @s nvarchar(max) 
   select @s = convert(nvarchar(max), replicate('.', 8000)) + 'Hi!' 
   select len(@s) -- returns 8003
   ```
3. Are there ways to *disable* the functionality? Does `sp_tableoption @OptionName=large value types out of row` or `OBJECTPROPERTY(id,'TableTextInRowLimit')` have anything to do with this?

   **Clarification**: My aim is not to use this functionality, but be aware of its existence, which may be indeed have been used by a higher privilege user that will prevent *me* from using the max size.
4. Any other points gladly welcome

Comment: Related - [Maximum size of a varchar(max) variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7611394/15498)

Comment: And there's never been a case when `nvarchar(max)` was 4000. It used to be the case that *the max keyword didn't exist in this context* and the maximum number you could specify was 4000 but that's not precisely the same. And besides, if you're affected by this, you've got far bigger issues since the last version without `max` support was SQL Server 2000 which is *long* out of support.

Comment: And there's plenty of questions about string concatenation which eventually will lead back to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of 8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever 1. Wow, even *more* than 2GB? Interesting. I'm fine with 2GB though, so I won't reasearch it much atm. 2. The tidbit that v2000 is the first with (or last without?) nax support is important to me, maybe an answer? Because I can't find a link for that on MS documentation, so I can never be sure.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis you should read the documentation instead of scattered answers that probably *don't* refer to your problem. Ther'es no confusion. The docs are *very* clear on all this. There was never any 4K character limit in the BLOB/CLOB types. `text/ntext/image` are deprecated since essentially forever. There are few references to the ancient types precisely because they *shouldn't* be used, ever. Those references say that they *shouldn't* be used.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I suspect you found some ancient legacy code that still used the old types and got confused? The change happened so long ago that people actually forgot about them. The changes were explained in a *lot* of local User Group and Microsoft events back then. That's 19 years ago. People don't talk about it anymore, just as they don't talk about the Visual Basic 6 type system

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few points here, as I can't fit into a comment.

1. Yes. `(n)varchar(MAX)` was [introduced in SQL Server 2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms170355%28v%3Dsql.90%29). Previously you had to make use of `text`, `ntext` and `image` for `varchar(MAX)`, `nvarchar(MAX)` and `varbinary(MAX)`. The old data type have been deprecated for a long time now and you should not be using them.
2. When combining data, [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is used to work out the final data type. When lengths are involved, the combined values of the lengths are used (A `varchar(10)` and a `varchar(100)` concatenated would return a `varchar(110)`. Note, however, that to achieve the usage of the `MAX` length, at least one string must be an `(n)varchar(MAX)`. `SELECT REPLICATE(N'A',3000) + REPLICATE(N'A',3000) AS S` would return a 4000 character string. [+ (String Concatenation) (Transact-SQL) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks):

   > If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of 8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur.
3. Disable what functionality? The usage of `(n)varchar(MAX)`? Why? If you wanted to stop people using a data type stop them using `(n)text` and `image`. In all seriousness though, you can't stop the usage of a data type. Perhaps you could get "clever" with DDL triggers, but I advise against it. 
   To answer the edit, `sp_tableoption` cannot be used to stop someone using a `MAX` length datatype no; my above point stands. To quote the documetation  ([sp_tableoption (Transact-SQL) - Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-tableoption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments):

   > *Large value types out of row:*
   >   1 = `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)`, `varbinary(max)`, `xml` and large user-defined type (UDT) columns in the table are stored out of row, with a 16-byte pointer to the root.
   >   0 = `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)`, `varbinary(max)`, `xml` and large UDT values are stored directly in the data row, up to a limit of 8000 bytes and as long as the value can fit in the record. If the value does not fit in the record, a pointer is stored in-row and the rest is stored out of row in the LOB storage space. 0 is the default value.
   >   Large user-defined type (UDT) applies to: SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2017.
   >   Use the `TEXTIMAGE_ON` option of `CREATE TABLE` to specify a location for storage of large data types.
4. Too broad for SO.

Comment: Since a comment from the OP indicated that they couldn't find the answer to 1 in the MS documentation, I've taken a liberty and added a link to your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I see you found the `+` documentation as well, hope you don't mind if I steal that citation.

Comment: I've added a clarification about 3.

Comment: Added some more clarification on 3 for you @GeorgeMenoutis, but doesn't chaneg the answer.