# Displaying a delimited string for values that are not in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When I have an SQL query with a `GROUP BY` clause, It is often very useful to see some of the un-grouped values for easier debugging.

My question is, how can I select a string that will be composed of the un-grouped values.
For example, in the following code:

```
SELECT  t2.ID 
        --,t1.Id    -- < how can I display this as a comma seperated string   
FROM t1 
     INNER JOIN t2 on t1.t2ID = t2.ID
GROUP BY t2.ID
```

I would like to have a way to select a string with `t1.Id`'s for each grouped record (e.g. `"42, 13, 18"`...).
How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you just need need values for debugging, `min()` and `max()` are the easiest way to get two values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178039/accomplishing-mysqls-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: While I like [the eventual duplicate that is proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/545672/61305), I don't like that it adds a comma to the end, and takes the length of every output value just to remove that last comma. I think that's grossly inexpensive and far prefer adding a comma to the beginning - then STUFF makes it easy to remove it without ever having to count characters.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559551/sql-server-equivalent-of-wm-concat-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are integer values, you can use a naked `XML PATH` transform to handle group concatenation for you (and this even supports predictable and well-defined order, unlike all other group concatenation methods - which have undefined behavior).

```
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(ID INT);
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),t2ID INT);

INSERT @t2(ID) VALUES(1),(2),(3);
INSERT @t1(t2ID) VALUES(1),(1),(1),(2);

SELECT t2.ID, t2IDs = STUFF((
  SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), t1.ID)
  FROM @t1 AS t1 WHERE t1.t2ID = t2.ID
  ORDER BY t1.ID
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM @t2 AS t2;
```

Results:

```
ID    t2IDs
----  -----
1     1,2,3
2     4
3     NULL
```

Note that you don't need `ID` in the `GROUP BY` clause, because you're no longer needing to filter out duplicates matched by virtue of the `JOIN`. Of course this assumes your column is named appropriately - if that column has duplicates with no `JOIN` involved at all, then it has a terribly misleading name. A column named `ID` should uniquely identify a row (but even better would be to call it what it is, and name it the same throughout the model, e.g. `CustomerID`, `OrderID`, `PatientID`, etc).

If you're dealing with strings, you need to account for cases where the string may contain XML-unsafe characters (e.g. `<`). In those cases, this is the method I've always used:

```
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
```