# SQL - combine multiple rows with similar username

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table with users who work at several office locations. These Locations are identified by a number and in my table, I have several users appearing on several rows for each office location they work at. What I want is a SQL query which will combine the records and show all the office locations in one field separated by a coma.

This is my original table:

```
Id    UserName    OfficeNumber
---   ---------   -------------
1     user01      200
2     user02      220
3     user01      290
4     user03      089
5     user02      019
```

I want my final table to look like below after running the query:

```
Id    UserName    OfficeNumber
---   ---------   -------------
1     user01      200, 290
2     user02      220, 019
3     user03      089
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What you have tried? You want to delete the row 4 & 5?

Comment: how are you deciding ID value in the result ?

Comment: Yes, rows 4 and 5 will be deleted, excerpt for the office number which will be consolidated with the office number in the first row in which the username appears in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL-Servers XML extensions to concatenate rows to columns:

```
SELECT  ID,
        UserName,
        OfficeNumber = STUFF((  SELECT  ',' + CAST(OfficeNumber AS VARCHAR(3))
                                FROM    YourTable b
                                WHERE   a.UserName = b.UserName
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    (   SELECT  ID = MIN(ID), UserName
            FROM    YourTable
            GROUP BY UserName
        ) a;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08cd7/1)**

There is [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10381512/1048425) where someone has asked the intricacies of how this method works, and there are a few answers, so I won't repeat the explanation here.

---

**EDIT**

Just seem that you are not taking the minimum ID for each username, but reassigning a new Number as ID, if ID's are to be reassinged based on the lowest original ID for each username then you can use:

```
SELECT  ID,
        UserName,
        OfficeNumber = STUFF((  SELECT  ',' + CAST(OfficeNumber AS VARCHAR(3))
                                FROM    YourTable b
                                WHERE   a.UserName = b.UserName
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    (   SELECT  ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(ID)), UserName
            FROM    YourTable
            GROUP BY UserName
        ) a;
```

**[Example on SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08cd7/2)**

Or if it is in alphabetical order you can use

```
SELECT  ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.UserName),
        UserName,
        OfficeNumber = STUFF((  SELECT  ',' + CAST(OfficeNumber AS VARCHAR(3))
                                FROM    YourTable b
                                WHERE   a.UserName = b.UserName
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    YourTable a
GROUP BY a.UserName
```

**[Example on SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08cd7/3)**

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cb88/3)**

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY c1.UserName) AS Id,
       c1.UserName,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' +x.OfficeNumber
        FROM Table1 x
        WHERE c1.UserName = x.UserName
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ),1,1,'') as OfficeNumber
FROM Table1 c1
GROUP BY c1.UserName
```

Result:

```
| ID | USERNAME | OFFICENUMBER |
|----|----------|--------------|
|  1 |   user01 |     200, 290 |
|  2 |   user02 |     220, 019 |
|  3 |   user03 |          089 |
```

Comment: I don't think it is an issue in this case since officenumber appears to be a standard numeric format. But just using `FOR XML PATH('')` without using the additional syntax I have (`, TYPE).value('.', NVARCHAR(MAX))`) will cause XML characters to be escaped. e.g. an office number of `<119>` will become `&lt;119&gt;`