# SQL finding unique combinations and number of occurances

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a ms sql database table where I want to find all the unique combinations of categories (CatId) that subscribers (SubId) have signed up for.

```
SubId CatId Cat 
4     39    Google Play
4     40    Kobo
4     43    Other
5     39    Google Play
5     43    Other
7     49    Amazon
7     39    Google Play
7     40    Kobo
6     39    Google Play
6     40    Kobo
6     43    Other
8     49    Amazon
8     39    Google Play
8     40    Kobo
9     38    Barnes & Noble
9     41    Smashwords
```

The output would hopefully be like:  (Where groupId is counter for the combinations)

```
GroupId CatId   Cat         Occurances
1        39     Google Play     2
1        40     Kobo            2
1        43     Other           2
2        39     Google Play     1
2        43     Other           1
3        49     Amazon          2
3        39     Google Play     2
3        40     Kobo            2
4        38     Barnes & Noble  1
4        41     Smashwords      1
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where does the `GroupId` come from?

Comment: Its basically a counter for the combinations of what the subscribers have selected, without it theres no way of grouping the categories together in the combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this is to first get a single row for each subID, and all their combinations by [concatenating the rows into a single column using the SQL Server XML extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381975/1048425):

```
SELECT  T.SubID,
        Combinations = STUFF((  SELECT  ',' + t2.Cat
                                FROM    T t2
                                WHERE   t.SubID = t2.SubID
                                ORDER BY t2.Cat
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    T
GROUP BY T.SubID;
```

This gives:

```
SUBID   COMBINATIONS
------+-------------------------
4     | Google Play,Kobo,Other
5     | Google Play,Other
6     | Google Play,Kobo,Other
7     | Amazon,Google Play,Kobo
8     | Amazon,Google Play,Kobo
9     | Barnes & Noble,Smashwords
```

You could just perform a simple count on this result set:

```
WITH Combinations AS
(   SELECT  T.SubID,
            Combinations = STUFF((  SELECT  ',' + t2.Cat
                                    FROM    T t2
                                    WHERE   t.SubID = t2.SubID
                                    ORDER BY t2.Cat
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    FROM    T
    GROUP BY T.SubID
)
SELECT  Combinations, Occurances = COUNT(*)
FROM    Combinations
GROUP BY Combinations;
```

[Which would give:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81956/11)

```
COMBINATIONS              | OCCURANCES
--------------------------+------------
Amazon,Google Play,Kobo   |     2
Barnes & Noble,Smashwords |     1
Google Play,Kobo,Other    |     2
Google Play,Other         |     1
```

Or to get the output you have shown, you need to join this back to your main table, and use the `Combinations` column above to group on:

```
WITH Combinations AS
(   SELECT  T.SubID,
            Combinations = STUFF((  SELECT  ',' + t2.Cat
                                    FROM    T t2
                                    WHERE   t.SubID = t2.SubID
                                    ORDER BY t2.Cat
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    FROM    T
    GROUP BY T.SubID
)
SELECT  GroupID = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY c.Combinations),
        T.CatID,
        T.Cat,
        Occurances = COUNT(DISTINCT T.SubID)
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN Combinations c
            ON c.SubID = T.SubID
GROUP BY T.CatID, T.Cat, c.Combinations;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81956/6)**

Comment: +1 for step by step explanation

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
select 
dense_rank() over (order by subid) as GroupID
,catID
,catName
,COUNT(*) as Occurances
 from table
group by subid, catID, catName
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to produce the unique combinations.