# Combine Unique Column Values Into One to Avoid Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For simplicity, assume I have two tables joined by `account#`.  The second table has two columns, `id and comment`.  Each account could have one or more comments and each unique comment has a unique id.

I need to write a t-sql query to generate one row for each account - which I assume means I need to combine as many comments as might exit for each account.  This assumes the result set will only show the account# once.  Simple?

Comment: What is exactly the expected output? And what dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server is a RDBMS best tuned for storing data and retrieving data, you can retrieve the desired data with one very simple query but the desired format should be handled with any of the reporting tools available like ssrs or crystal reports

Your query will be a simple inner join something like this

```
SELECT A.Account , B.Comment
FROM TableA AS A INNER JOIN TableB AS B
ON A.Account = B.Account
```

Now you can use your reporting tool to Group all the Comments by Account when Displaying data.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with M. Ali, but if you don't have that option, the following will work.

```
SELECT [accountID]
 , [name]
 , (SELECT CAST(Comment + ', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
     FROM [comments] 
     WHERE (accountID = accounts.accountID) 
     FOR XML PATH ('')
  ) AS Comments
FROM accounts
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf83d/4/0)

Comment: My actual three fields are Acctno, ID and Comment.  They are from table dbo.Workout_Comments.  Since I do not have rights to create functions as you suspected, I tried using my my fields and table in your query, and I get an (Invalid object name 'Comments) referencing Line 1 so I must be misinterpreting your solution. Greatly appreciate any clarification.  Thanks!

Comment: I assume [name] would be replaced by my field Acctno?

Comment: Give me the breakout of each table and its fields.

Comment: Select
 [ID],
 [Acctno],
 
 (Select Cast (Comment + ', ' as varchar(max))

  From dbo.Workout_Group_Comments
  
  Where (ID = dbo.Workout_Group_Comments.ID)
 
  For XML Path ('')

 )As Comments

From dbo.Workout_Group_Comments

Comment: The above works BUT it does not combine the unique comment fields into one so that only one row is rendered per account - if an account has 3 rows (comments) that account has 3 rows...  Thanks!

Comment: I'm keeping this to one table to keep it simple

Comment: Keeping it to one table makes it interesting.  I am assuming that the Acctno repeats in this table (you use it to know which comment is for which account).  Try this:   Select DISTINCT [Acctno], 
(Select Cast (Comment + ', ' as varchar(max)) 
 From #Workout_Group_Comments 
 Where Acctno = WGC.Acctno
 For XML Path ('') ) As Comments 
From #Workout_Group_Comments AS WGC

Comment: Here's an example of the resulting data set: ID Acctno Comment 21 1005 Here is my comment 1 22 1005 Here is my comment 2 23 1005 Here is my comment 3

Comment: Since your data is in one table, you can't include the ID.  It should be useless anyway since it looks as if it is just an Indentity field.  When asking a question like this, it is always good to give your table structures, data and expected output.  This will make it easier to answer the question in the manner you need and it will happen more quickly.

Comment: I think you're missing a `GROUP BY`. The nested `SELECT` should return one row for each unique AccountID so I think this should/would work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381512/what-this-query-does-to-create-comma-delimited-list-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

In my actual project I have this exact situation.
What you need is a solution to aggregate the comments in order to show only one line per `account#`.

I solve it by creating a function to concatenate the comments, like this:

```
create function dbo.aggregateComments( @accountId integer, @separator varchar( 5 ) )
as
begin;
    declare @comments varchar( max ); set @comments = '';

    select @comments = @comments + @separator + YouCommentsTableName.CommentColumn
      from dbo.YouCommentsTableNAme
     where YouCommentsTableName.AccountId = @accountId;

    return @comments;
end;
```

You can use it on you query this way:

```
select account#, dbo.aggretateComments( account#, ',' )
  from dbo.YourAccountTableName
```

Creating a function will give you a common place to retrieve your comments. It's a good programming practice.