# concatenate indeterminate numbers of strings in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I need to send out an email in bulk, with the email containing each course associated with that particular user's email. The following query will return a list of all courses and users associated with them.

```
select (cm.course_id + ': '+ cm.course_name) as course,
u.lastname, u.firstname, u.email from course_users cu
join users u on u.pk1 = cu.users_pk1
join course_main cm on cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
```

The trouble is that for the Mail Merge to work properly, **I need each user listed only once, and all associated courses in a single (delimited) cell for that row.**

Any help is appreciated!

*EDIT: Removing text about the CONCAT() function because it's just distracting.*

Comment: Be clear: is mysql or MS-SQL your database?

Comment: Take a look at `STUFF`...

Comment: Why would the `CONCAT()` function help?, are you thinking of `GROUP_CONCAT()`, which isn't available for any version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Lamak Yes, I was hoping I could manipulate CONCAT() in some iterative way but it's a moot point since I'm on the wrong version anyway.

Comment: `CONCAT()` only works across a single row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQL Server's XML extensions to concatenate rows:

```
SELECT  Course = STUFF((SELECT  ';' + cm.course_id + ': '+ cm.course_name
                        FROM    course_users cu
                                INNER JOIN course_main cm
                                    ON cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
                        WHERE   u.pk1 = cu.users_pk1
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        u.lastname, 
        u.firstname, 
        u.email
FROM    users u;
```

For a more detailed explanation of how this works see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381975/1048425).

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94f87/1)**

**EDIT**

To limit this to only users on a course you can move the logic to within an APPLY, then check the result is not null:

```
SELECT  Course = STUFF(c.course.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        u.lastname, 
        u.firstname, 
        u.email
FROM    users u
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  ';' + cm.course_id + ': '+ cm.course_name
            FROM    course_users cu
                    INNER JOIN course_main cm
                        ON cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
            WHERE   u.pk1 = cu.users_pk1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) c (course)
WHERE   c.course IS NOT NULL;
```

or add an exists clause:

```
SELECT  Course = STUFF((SELECT  ';' + cm.course_id + ': '+ cm.course_name
                        FROM    course_users cu
                                INNER JOIN course_main cm
                                    ON cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
                        WHERE   u.pk1 = cu.users_pk1
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        u.lastname, 
        u.firstname, 
        u.email
FROM    users u
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM course_users cu WHERE u.pk1 = cu.users_pk1);
```

**[Examples of both on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9dc6/3)**

Comment: These GROUP_CONCAT queries are always a race. :-) +1 and also +1 for your explanation in the other answer.

Comment: You are the wind beneath my wings.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ha, a race I am not overly proud of winning given I answered at 8.30pm on a Friday night. Perhaps I need to get out more. Thanks though.

Comment: It is the STUFF function, and removing the first character was by design. The first character is `;` which I intended to be cut off, so you end up with a list like "ID1: Name1;ID2: Name2;ID3: Name3", not ";ID1: Name1; ID2:...". If you have changed what is inside the subquery then yes it may well be removing the first character.