# Concatenate Column values from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please consider the following temp table:

```
DocID  Object  Field Value
--------------------------
 1      1       1        A
 2      1       1        B
 3      1       1        C
 4      1       2        A
 5      1       2        B
 6      2       1        F
 7      2       2        G
 8      2       2        H
 9      3       1        X
10      3       2        Y
11      3       3        Z
12      3       3        Z
13      3       3        Z
```

I would like to get the following result from a query:

```
Object  Field  Values
---------------------
1       1      A;B;C
1       2      A;B
2       1      F
2       2      G;H
3       1      X
3       2      Y
3       3      Z
```

In other words:

I would like to concatenate all `values` for each `field` for each `object`.

If for the same `object` for the same `field`, the same `value` exists (only the DocID is different), then the result should only show this repeating value once. Without this requirement, the result would look like:

```
Object  Field  Values
---------------------
1       1      A;B;C
1       2      A;B
2       1      F
2       2      G;H
3       1      X
3       2      Y
3       3      Z;Z;Z  <------- repeating values
```

In any scripting language, I would put the `#temptable` in an array and loop through it, but this time I have to accomplish this in SQL (Server 2008).

Is this even possible? Does SQL Server support looping through a `#temptable` or any other resultset and if so, could you give me pointers as how to solve this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL Server's XML Extensions to do this:

```
SELECT  Object,
        Field,
        [Values] = STUFF((SELECT ';' + Value
                        FROM #TempTable AS T2
                        WHERE T2.Object = T.Object
                        AND T2.Field = T.Field
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

FROM    #temptable AS T
GROUP BY Object, Field;
```

For a more detailed explanation of how this method works see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381975/1048425)

**EDIT**

If you only want unique values in the `Values` column, then you can just add `DISTINCT` to your subquery:

```
SELECT  Object,
        Field,
        [Values] = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ';' + Value
                        FROM #TempTable AS T2
                        WHERE T2.Object = T.Object
                        AND T2.Field = T.Field
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

FROM    #temptable AS T
GROUP BY Object, Field;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot an important requirement though. Please have a look at the updated OP. Is this possible?