# How to merge several records in one using COALESCE in MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm guering three tables from the DataBase with the idea to extract information for a certain `Client` so I get single values from all columns except one.

My tables are :

- `Client :: (ClientId | ClientName)`
- `Notifications :: (NotificationId | NotificiationText)`
- `ClientsNotifications :: (ClientId | NotificationId)`

A single client may have multiple notifications related to him, but I want to get them in a single row so after little research I decied that I should use `COALESCE`.

I made this query :

```
SELECT c.ClientName, (COALESCE(n.NotificiationText,'') + n.NotificiationText + ';')
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Client] AS c
LEFT JOIN [MyDB].[dbo].[ClientsNotifications] AS cn 
ON c.ClientId = cn.ClientId
LEFT JOIN [MyDB].[dbo].[Notifications] AS n
ON c.ClientId = cn.ClientId
AND cn.NotificationId = n.NotificationId
WHERE c.ClientId = 1
```

For this particular user I have two notifications, the result I get is - two rows, on the first row I have the first notification concatenated for itself (I have two times the same string) on the second row I have the second notification concateneated for itself again.

So There are three things that I want but don't know how to do -

1. Right now for column name I get `(No column name)` so I want to give it one
2. I want the two notifications (or as many as they are) concatenated in a single row
3. I want to determine some delimeter so when I fetch the records I can perform `split`. In my example I use this - `';')` which I think should act as delimeter but the concatenated strings that I have are not separeted by `;` or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your column name an alias in the same way you do for a table, e.g.

```
SELECT  <expression> AS ColumnAlias
```

However, for [reasons detailed here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) I prefer using:

```
SELECT ColumnAlias = <expression>
```

Then to get multiple rows into columns you can use SQL Servers XML extensions to achieve this:

```
SELECT  c.ClientName, 
        Notifications = STUFF(( SELECT  ';' + n.NotificationText
                                FROM    [MyDB].[dbo].[ClientsNotifications] AS cn 
                                        INNER JOIN [MyDB].[dbo].[Notifications] AS n
                                            ON n.NotificationId = cn.NotificationId
                                WHERE   c.ClientId = cn.ClientId
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    [MyDB].[dbo].[Client] AS c
WHERE   c.ClientId = 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7aa33/2)**

An explanation of how this method works can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381975/1048425) so I shalln't repeat it here.

Comment: Thanks, pretty complicated for my `MS SQL` skills, but it works just fine by just copy-pasting it. Perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick to doing what you want to do. As it's written right now, you're just grabbing stuff off the same row. Also, multiple conditions on the second left join are unnecessary.

```
DECLARE @clientName VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @clientName = c.ClientName
     , @text = (CASE
                   WHEN n.NotificationText IS NOT NULL THEN @text + ';' + n.NotificationText
                   ELSE @text
                END)
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Client] AS c
LEFT JOIN [MyDB].[dbo].[ClientsNotifications] AS cn 
ON c.ClientId = cn.ClientId
LEFT JOIN [MyDB].[dbo].[Notifications] AS n
ON cn.NotificationId = n.NotificationId
WHERE c.ClientId = 1

SELECT @clientName AS ClientName, @text AS Notifications
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax, you get the following error *`A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.`*

Comment: @GarethD Edit: nevermind, found why my initial answer was bad and I'd already fixed it anyway. Btw, this is still a better solution than yours :P

Comment: It really isn't a better solution, it is much less adaptable as it will only work for a single client, if you changed the where clause to `WHERE c.ClientId IN (1, 2)` you would get incorrect results, and need to use a cursor to loop through each client. As discussed in [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) (written by a SQL Server MVP) a CLR function is ultimately the best option, but the next best is using `FOR XML`.