# Query to count how often the same detail data is stored in master - detail

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, master-detail

I am a bit stuck with building a query to count how often the same detail data is stored in a master-detail relationship in a ms sql server database.

I got a master table, which is not that much important.

```
MASTER_ID 
1  
2  
3
4
```

What's important is the following detail table.

```
DID MASTERID No  Value
1     1        1   220
2     1        2   250
3     1        3   250        
4     2        1   220
5     2        2   250
6     3        1   220
7     3        2   250
8     4        1   220
9     4        2   230
```

The detail table has n rows, the column `No` (int)  is a sequential number for the same `masterid`. The value is a decimal value. 
I would like to group and count the rows that I know how often the exact same detail data is used for the master rows. Definition of the same data: The same number of detail rows and each detail row must be the same (columns no and value).

The wanted result:

```
Count  No  Value
1      1   220   (DID 1)
1      2   250   (DID 2)
1      3   250   (DID 3)        
2      1   220   (DID 4 and 6)
2      2   250   (DID 5 and 7)
1      1   220   (DID 8)
1      2   230   (DID 9)
```

The first three rows have count 1 because there is no other master row with exactly these three no and value details. The next two rows have count 2 because there are two master rows which have 1-220 and 2-250 as detail rows. The last two rows have count one because there is only one master which has 1-220 and 2-230 as detail rows.

It's important to understand that for example

```
No  Value
1 150
2 170
```

and

```
No  Value
1 170 
2 150
```

is not seen as same detail data because of the different order (column no).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried looking at COUNT?

Comment: I don't get it, how do you arrive at a count of 2 in the expected results? Can you add the DID's that would contribute to each row of your expected result perhaps?

Comment: added the DID's and more info about the wanted result set, i hope its more clear now. GarethD approach is to concat the detail data and then add it to the master rows, so its possible to group by that. This works fine. I guess there is no other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I get this now, I think what you are after is comparing MasterID's that have the same value for **all** rows. This means your first step is to compare MasterID's to see if they are comparable. The best way to do this is to concatenate all rows together for each Master ID, building an out put like:

```
MASTER_ID   | No:Value
1           | [1:220][2:250][3:250]
2           | [1:220][2:250]  
3           | [1:220][2:250]
4           | [1:220][2:230]
```

Here you can see that 3 and 4 are comparable because they have the same result for the `No:Value` column.

This can be achieved using [SQL Server's XML extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10381975/1048425):

```
SELECT  m.MasterID,
        NoValue = ( SELECT  QUOTENAME(CAST(No AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                                + ':' + CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(10)))
                    FROM    Detail AS d
                    WHERE   d.MasterID = m.MasterID
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM    Master AS m;
```

Then you can join this output to your details table giving:

```
DID MASTERID No  Value NoValue
1     1        1   220 [1:220][2:250][3:250]
2     1        2   250 [1:220][2:250][3:250]
3     1        3   250 [1:220][2:250][3:250]
4     2        1   220 [1:220][2:250]
5     2        2   250 [1:220][2:250]
6     3        1   220 [1:220][2:250]
7     3        2   250 [1:220][2:250]
8     4        1   220 [1:220][2:230]
9     4        2   230 [1:220][2:230]
```

Then it is just a case of counting grouping by `No`, `Value` and `NoValue`:

```
WITH MasterValue AS
(   SELECT  m.MasterID,
            NoValue = ( SELECT  QUOTENAME(CAST(No AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                                    + ':' + CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(10)))
                        FROM    Detail AS d
                        WHERE   d.MasterID = m.MasterID
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                       ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    FROM    Master AS m
), GroupedDetail AS
(   SELECT  d.DID, d.MasterID, d.No, d.Value, mv.NoValue
    FROM    Detail AS d
            INNER JOIN MasterValue AS mv
                ON mv.MasterID = d.MasterID
)
SELECT  Count = COUNT(*), No, Value
FROM    GroupedDetail
GROUP BY No, Value, NoValue;
```

This is the step by step process, however, you can simplify the above into this:

```
SELECT  Count = COUNT(*), d.No, d.Value
FROM    Detail AS d
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  CAST(No AS VARCHAR(10)) + ':' + CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(10)) + ','
            FROM    Detail AS nv
            WHERE   nv.MasterID = d.MasterID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) AS nv (NoValue)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT nv.NoValue.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) AS nv2 (NoValue)
GROUP BY d.No, d.Value, nv2.NoValue
ORDER BY MIN(d.DID);
```

Comment: yes thats exactly what I wanted to do. thank you. I also thought of creating a function which concats the detail data as string and add it to the master table, then group by it. but i thought there would be maybe a more simple way.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, I am not sure this is what you are looking for, so let me know what is missing and we can build from there.

SELECT MASTERID, No, Value, COUNT()
FROM detail
GROUP BY MASTERID, No, Value

Comment: thx but the problem with the simple count is that you just compare how often one master has the same detail. but not if different masters have the same values as details. it's way more complex.