# I want to merge date and amount into a string

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using the query which merges date column and amount column into a string, but as we are querying it by policy number, it is getting many rows, my thing is to merge these different values of the columns to one.

example:

```
2014/09/01 733.00
2012/08/01 322.02
```

so these are the different rows for one policy number, now I want them to be also in one single string as :

```
2014/09/01 733.00 2012/08/01 322.02
```

If they are two rows, then also the value of my column should merge all the values of dates and amounts into single string for that particular policy number.

The query I am using is :

```
SELECT
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, BSD.BILL_SCH_DTL_BILL_DT, 111), 10)
    + ' '+ CONVERT (VARCHAR(50),BSD.BILL_SCH_DTL_DRV_AMT ,128)Schedule_pymts, *
From POLICY_PERIOD_BILLING_SCHEDULE PB
JOIN BILLING_SCHEDULE_DETAIL BSD
        ON BSD.PLCY_PRD_BILL_SCH_ID = PB.PLCY_PRD_BILL_SCH_ID
        AND BSD.BILL_SCH_DTL_DRV_AMT <> 0
        AND BSD.VOID_IND = 'n'
```

but this only merges one month and one amount together, but I need all the months of amount to be in one string(column) for that particular policy number.

Comment: You will have to use `group by` the month

Comment: You may be able to use the function `CONCAT()` -- with `GROUP BY`, as Rahul says.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`FOR XML PATH` to concatenate your rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381512/what-this-query-does-to-create-comma-delimited-list-sql-server/10381975#10381975). I think something like this will work:

```
SELECT  PB.*,
        RTRIM((SELECT   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), BSD.BILL_SCH_DTL_BILL_DT, 111)+ ' '
                        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), BSD.BILL_SCH_DTL_DRV_AMT, 128) + ' '
                FROM    BILLING_SCHEDULE_DETAIL AS BSD
                WHERE   BSD.PLCY_PRD_BILL_SCH_ID = PB.PLCY_PRD_BILL_SCH_ID
                AND     BSD.BILL_SCH_DTL_DRV_AMT <> 0
                AND     BSD.VOID_IND = 'n'
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) AS Schedule_pymts
FROM    POLICY_PERIOD_BILLING_SCHEDULE AS PB;
```

*N.B. Don't use `SELECT *` - explicitly list your columns, but I don't know what they are so can't above*

Comment: I tried the above code, but I am getting some errors on executing the code. Can you please check the code once again, Thanks in advance

Comment: I have copied whole thing and, tried to execute from my side, But I got the error incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'                                       And it also shows red marks at pb.* and at line ').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) AS Schedule_pymts'   ans at line 'FROM    BILLING_SCHEDULE_DETAIL AS BSD'

Comment: I think it was just an extra bracket in the subquery - please try again now.