# combine data of multiple rows from multiple tables and show in single row

Tags: sql-server

I am writing query for getting result from multiple table it gives multiple rows with repeating values in all column expect one i want that columns to be short and show in single row, these are my tables

Table Name: AppUesrs

```
Id  Name    Gender
1   Goga    M
2   Maja    M
3   Phadu   M
4   Kaku    F
5   Seefa   F
```

Table Name: AppProducts

```
Id  Name    Value
1   Bc090   10
2   Bc080   15
3   Mc070   2
4   Mc100   16
5   Bc110   15
```

Table Name: AppOrders

```
Id  Date        ExpDate
1   08/9/2014   10/10/2015
2   18/9/2014   08/11/2015
3   20/9/2014   25/12/2015
4   01/10/2014  14/12/2015
5   19/10/2014  15/2/2016
```

and
Table Name: ProductOwners

```
OId  PId UId
1   1   2
1   2   2
1   5   2
2   3   5
3   4   4
3   3   4
3   5   4
3   1   4
```

I am writing query for it and it show data like this

```
select O.Id, P.ProductName, U.Name ,O.Date,O.ExpDate 
from AppProductOwners PO, AppProducts P, AppOrders O, AppUsers U 
Where PO.AppOrderId = O.Id AND PO.ProductsId = P.Id AND PO.AppUserId = U.Id
```

it is giving data like

```
O.Id    P.Name  U.Name  O.Date  O.ExpDate
   1    Bc090   Maja    08/9/2014   10/10/2015
   1    Bc080   Maja    08/9/2014   10/10/2015
   1    Bc110   maja    08/9/2014   10/10/2015
```

and i want data like

```
  O.Id  P.Name             U.Name   O.Date  O.ExpDate
   1    Bc090,Bc080,Bc110   Maja    08/9/2014   10/10/2015
```

Kindly if any one help me writing this query

If I write it like

```
SELECT  O.ID,
    PName = STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + P.ProductName
                    FROM   AppProductOwners PO
                            INNER JOIN AppProducts P
                                ON P.Id = PO.ProductsId
                    AND   U.Id = PO.AppUserId
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
    U.FirstName, U.LastName,
    O.Date,
    o.ExpDate
FROM    AppUsers U
    INNER JOIN AppOrders O
        ON u.id = O.ID;
```

it shows nothing , and if i write it like

```
SELECT  O.ID,
    PName = STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + P.ProductName
                    FROM   AppProductOwners PO
                            INNER JOIN AppProducts P
                                ON P.Id = PO.ProductsId
                    AND   AppUsers.Id = PO.AppUserId
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
    U.FirstName, U.LastName,
    O.Date,
    o.ExpDate
FROM    AppUsers U
    INNER JOIN AppOrders O
        ON u.id = O.ID;
```

It gives error

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "AppUsers.Id" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL Servers XML extensions to concatenate rows into a single column:

```
SELECT  O.ID,
        PName = STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + P.Name
                        FROM    PO
                                INNER JOIN P
                                    ON P.ID = PO.PID
                        WHERE   U.ID = PO.UID
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        U.Name,
        O.Date,
        o.ExpDate
FROM    U
        INNER JOIN O
            ON u.id = O.ID;
```

For a more detailed explanation of how this works see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381512/what-this-query-does-to-create-comma-delimited-list-sql-server/10381975#10381975)

If you only want to include rows where `PName` is not null, then it is probably easier to adjust the query slightly to use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  O.ID,
        PName = STUFF(p.PName.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        U.Name,
        O.Date,
        o.ExpDate
FROM    U
        INNER JOIN O
            ON u.id = O.ID
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  ',' + P.Name
            FROM    PO
                    INNER JOIN P
                        ON P.ID = PO.PID
            WHERE   U.ID = PO.UID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) p (PName)
WHERE   p.Pname IS NOT NULL;
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79a62f/4)**

---

**EDIT**

I think I misunderstood your schema initially, and how `Orders` linked to `Users`, I think this will work as required:

```
SELECT  O.ID,
        PName = STUFF(p.PName.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
        U.Name,
        O.Date,
        o.ExpDate
FROM    AppUsers AS U
        CROSS JOIN AppOrders AS O
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  ',' + P.Name
            FROM    AppProductOwners AS PO
                    INNER JOIN AppProducts AS P
                        ON P.ID = PO.PID
            WHERE   U.ID = PO.UID
            AND     O.ID = PO.OID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ) p (PName)
WHERE   p.Pname IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: it is not working . Kindly will u recheck the answer ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"it is not working"* please - Any error message? Not the results you are expecting? My knowledge of SQL is not bad, I am however rubbish at mind reading.

Comment: Dear first it gives error "The multi-part identifier "U.ID" could not be bound." if we gives reference of U from  below part it shows empty ..

Comment: Then one of two things is happening - either your table structure is not what you have posted in the question (is your table actually called "U"?), or you are not running the exact queries I have posted. The SQL Fiddle provided in the answer shows that both queries work fine.

Comment: My table name is Users , i write it Users as U, it made easy to fetch fields from table, and i post the same query , u can say i copy past your code and name it as i write in question

Comment: my table structure is same as i provided except their names

Comment: I don't know what more I can do to help, as I have said the queries work fine for me (on SQL Server 2008, and 2012), the error `The multi-part identifier "U.ID" could not be bound.` indicates either that you don't have a table called `U`, or none of the tables have an alias `U`, or the table does not contain a column `ID`. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I checked it again with every single detail , i am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: Can you please edit the question and show the **Exact** query you are running, and the line at which the error is occurring. Thanks

Comment: I Update my Question now it is same as i am doing