# SQL Declare Query only returns 1 row result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a result from our db with one identifier (ArtNr) and one big chunk of text that also contains returns (Edit),
I also want the text from the (Edit) column to be stringed? 
(like this: "texttexttext" it's the "" I need in the beginning and end of the text)

I have come up with the query below but it only gives 1 row in reply (should be like 4000) and it does of course not give me the Edit captioned with "" since I have no clue how to do it :)

Thanks in advance! /Christian

```
USE MSPes2t 

DECLARE @result nvarchar(max) , @test nvarchar(255)

SELECT @result = AR.Edit , @test = AR.ArtNr

FROM DBO.AR

WHERE AR.ArtNr = '%'

ORDER BY AR.ArtNr

SELECT  @test AS artnr,
        @result AS edit
```

This is the result im searching for:
Like this:

```
ArtNr | Edit
------+----------------------------------------
12001 | "edit"
12002 | "edit"
28001 | "edit"
```

Comment: Side note: `WHERE AR.ArtNr = '12001'

ORDER BY AR.ArtNr` - what's that order meant to achieve? We know all rows have the same value for that column so no sorting is required.

Comment: Note/Correction: Sorry sent you a example where i tried with 1 specific row, artnr 12001. the WHERE could be just anything % (I want all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should give you the desired results (although I am not exactly sure how you want to delimit your edits, I have used a semi-colon):

```
SELECT  ArtNr = '12001',
        Edit = STUFF((  SELECT  ';"' + ar.Edit + '"'
                        FROM    dbo.AR
                        WHERE   AR.ArtNr = '12001'
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
```

A full explanation of how using the xml extension `FOR XML PATH()` works to concanate rows into a single field can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381512/what-this-query-does-to-create-comma-delimited-list-sql-server/10381975#10381975)

If you need to get the edits concatenated for more than one ArtNo then you could use somethig like:

```
SELECT  ar.ArtNr,
        Edit = STUFF((  SELECT  ';"' + ar2.Edit + '"'
                        FROM    dbo.AR AS ar2
                        WHERE   AR2.ArtNr = ar.ArtNr
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    dbo.Ar
WHERE   ar.ArtNr IN ('12001', '12002')
GROUP BY ar.ArtNr;
```

**SIMPLE WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
DECLARE @AR TABLE (ArtNr VARCHAR(5), Edit NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @AR (ArtNr, Edit)
VALUES ('12001', 'editeditedit'), ('12001', 'edit2 edit2'),
    ('12001', 'edit3'), ('12002', 'edit2 edit2');

SELECT  ar.ArtNr,
        Edit = STUFF((  SELECT  ';"' + ar2.Edit + '"'
                        FROM    @AR AS ar2
                        WHERE   AR2.ArtNr = ar.ArtNr
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    @AR AS ar
WHERE   ar.ArtNr IN ('12001', '12002')
GROUP BY ar.ArtNr;
```

Gives:

```
ArtNr | Edit
------+----------------------------------------
12001 | "editeditedit";"edit2 edit2";"edit3"
12002 | "editeditedit"
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on your required output I think your query is as simple as concatenating `"` to either end of your edit field:

```
SELECT  AR.ArtNr,
        '"' + AR.edit + '"' AS Edit
FROM    DBO.AR
WHERE   AR.ArtNr = '%'
ORDER BY ArtNr;
```

In SQL Server 2012 and later you can use `CONCAT` but it doesn't offer much advantage in this scenario.

Comment: Impressive the smallest code gave the correct answer, huge thanks for your support!