# Make rows to columns in SQL Server for each record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a large(ish) DB. Simply put customer records. Now I have two tables; one is `CustomerInfo` and `PhoneNumbers`. Some sample data would be,

``````````````
CustomerInfo
`````````````
CustID  |   CustName    |   CustomerLocation
--------+---------------+--------------------
1       |   Paul        |   Bristol
2       |   Eugin       |   Bournemouth
3       |   Francis     |   London

PhoneNumbers
````````````
PhoneID |   CustID  |   PhoneNumber
--------+-----------+----------------
1       |   1       |   0117123456
2       |   2       |   0120212345
3       |   2       |   0784256864
4       |   3       |   0204587895
``````````````

Now as you could see, `Paul` and `Francis` have just one number, but `Eugin` has two. In a normal world, if I join the two tables as,

```
SELECT
    c.CustName,
    p.PhoneNumber
FROM
    CustomerInfo c
    JOIN 
    PhoneNumbers p
    ON c.CustID = p.CustID
```

I would get,

```
CustName    |   PhoneNumber
------------+--------------------
Paul        |   0117123456
Eugin       |   0120212345
Eugin       |   0784256864
Francis     |   0204587895
```

This is right, but I am running another Query that need the result to be,

```
CustName    |   PhoneNumber1    |   PhoneNumber2
------------+-------------------+---------------
Paul        |   0117123456      |   NULL
Eugin       |   0120212345      |   0784256864
Francis     |   0204587895      |   NULL
```

I could write a table variable from a function. But as this is going to be part of a Query, I was hoping if there were any other solution.

**EDIT -** I would like to highlight the section, `as this is going to be part of a Query, I was hoping if there were any other solution`, The actual query is going to be,

```
SELECT 
    per.[PersonId],
    per.[ClientReference],
    sal.SalutationName,
    per.[FirstName],
    per.[LastName],
    per.[DateOfBirth],
    per.[Password]
FROM 
    [Customers].[people].[Person] per
    JOIN 
    [Customers].[people].[Salutation] sal
    ON sal.SalutationId = per.SalutationId
```

What I would like is,

```
SELECT 
    per.[PersonId],
    per.[ClientReference],
    sal.SalutationName,
    per.[FirstName],
    per.[LastName],
    per.[DateOfBirth],
    per.[Password],
    pn.[PhoneNumber1], --Made up column, there is only one column in the pn table
    pn.[PhoneNumber2]  --Made up column, there is only one column in the pn table
FROM 
    [Customers].[people].[Person] per
    JOIN 
    [Customers].[people].[Salutation] sal
    ON sal.SalutationId = per.SalutationId
    JOIN 
    [Customers].[comms].[PhoneNumber] pn
    ON per.PersonId = pn.PersonId
```

Comment: This is a pivot query. **Important question:** Can you have "unlimited" phone numbers per customer? Or is there a limit ?

Comment: @SQLPolice, I do not have at the present time more than 2, however. Even if we have, I would want just the first two. Thanks, I will look into this. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) to give each phone number a rank within its customer ID, then use this to [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the data:

```
SELECT  CustID,
        PhoneNumber1 = pvt.[1],
        PhoneNumber2 = pvt.[2],
        PhoneNumber3 = pvt.[3],
        PhoneNumber4 = pvt.[4]
FROM    (   SELECT  CustID, 
                    PhoneNumber,
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY Phonenumber)
            FROM    PhoneNumbers 
        ) AS pn
        PIVOT 
        (   MAX(Phonenumber)
            FOR RowNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4]) -- INCREASE/DECREASE COLUMNS AS REQUIRED
        ) AS pvt;
```

If you have an unknown number of phone numbers and want to include them all where applicable, I would be inclined to use a single column and display a comma delimited list, which you can do using [SQL Server's XML extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381512/what-this-query-does-to-create-comma-delimited-list-sql-server/10381975#10381975). This is easier than using dynamic SQL, and also easier for anything dealing with the results as you have a known number of columns being returned:

```
SELECT  c.CustID,
        c.CustName,
        c.CustomerLocation,
        PhoneNumbers = STUFF((  SELECT  ',' + p.PhoneNumber
                                FROM    PhoneNumbers AS p
                                WHERE   p.CustID = c.CustID
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    CustomerInfo  AS c;
```

Comment: @SQLPolice I would increase the number of columns, which is done by changing the number arguments in the `PIVOT` function right next to the comment that states *"INCREASE/DECREASE COLUMNS AS REQUIRED"*

Comment: Yes, but what if you want to be totally flexible ? ...  write 356 columns ? .... The only solution which supports "unlimited" phone number columns is to write a procedure with dynamic SQL.

Comment: I agree to the XML solution, this is a very godo solution in many cases. It depends on how the solution will be needed. If you want to load the view into excel spreadsheet, then you would again need a solution with "real" columns.

Comment: There is no mention of this requirement in the question, so I don't like to jump to conclusions about what the OP may or may not require. Since dynamic SQL should be used sparingly, and with caution, I would not go out of my way to recommend it where it may not be required.

Comment: I agree to your opinion to dynamic SQL. That's why I asked the OP in the comment. Dynamic SQL can be great, but can also open up a pandora's box, so better weigh carefully.

Comment: Thanks @GarethD, I will try this now, and give a comment. From what I see, this could work, although I was a bit weary of using SubQueries. Will have a look. :)

Comment: Thank you @GarethD, I managed to use that as my SubQuery, and it is getting the intended result. Execution time is 17 seconds for 23K records. Not that bad, will see if I can do something to increase performance. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want, **Pivot with dynamic SQL**

```
declare @maxcount as int = (select top 1 count(phonenumber) from PhoneNumbers group by custid order by count(phonenumber) desc)
declare @dynamicsql as nvarchar(max) = 'select * from
(
SELECT
    c.CustName,
    p.PhoneNumber,
    ''PhoneNumber''+convert(nvarchar(10),(row_number() over (partition by custname order by c.CustName))) as rn
FROM
    CustomerInfo c
    inner join 
    PhoneNumbers p
    ON c.CustID = p.CustID
) as sourcetable
pivot
(
    MAX(Phonenumber)
    FOR rn IN ('

declare @counter as int = 1
while (@counter<=@maxcount)
begin
set @dynamicsql = @dynamicsql +'[PhoneNumber'+convert(nvarchar(10),@counter)+'],'
set @counter=@counter+1
end

set @dynamicsql = substring(@dynamicsql,0,len(@dynamicsql))

set @dynamicsql = @dynamicsql + ')
)
as pivottable'

print @dynamicsql
exec (@dynamicsql)
```

For your reference

[image]

Comment: Pravin, there is no doubt this works, but as I mentioned I am using this as part of another query that has other JOINS, so in that case, how would I use a Dynamic SQL along with my existing Query?

Comment: Put that into string query

Comment: I have not taken this as my answer, but I really do like the way you have gone about doing this, I will play with this. Cheers.:)

Comment: Have fun. Cheers! @PaulFrancis

Comment: Hi @PaulFrancis, I have mailed you. :) see you there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gareth, I managed to find my solution to this, I have accepted his answer, but thought I would share how I managed to get the desired result. This is the SQL I have used.

```
SELECT 
    per.[PersonId],
    per.[ClientReference],
    sal.SalutationName,
    per.[FirstName],
    per.[LastName],
    per.[DateOfBirth],
    per.[Password],
    tmpQ.PhoneNumber1,
    tmpQ.PhoneNumber2
FROM 
    [Customers].[people].[Person] per
    JOIN 
    [Customers].[people].[Salutation] sal
    ON sal.SalutationId = per.SalutationId
    JOIN 
    (SELECT  
         [PersonId],
         PhoneNumber1 = pvt.[1],
         PhoneNumber2 = pvt.[2]
     FROM (SELECT  
              [PersonId], 
              Number,
              RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY Number)
           FROM [Customers].[comms].[PhoneNumber]) AS pn
           PIVOT (MAX(Number) FOR RowNum IN ([1], [2])) AS pvt
     ) tmpQ 
    ON tmpQ.PersonId = per.PersonId
```