# SQL Server Add a total row in Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have a dynamic `Pivot` query which looks like:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @start AS DateTime
DECLARE @end AS DateTime
DECLARE @business AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @start = '2015-01-01';
SET @end   = '2015-12-01';
SET @business = 'EUR';

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(date1)
FROM (  

    SELECT m.date1, m.date2 FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(nvarchar(50),   DATENAME(m, date) 
                               + ', ' 
                               + DATENAME(yyyy,date)) as date1, date as date2  

        FROM  bus_best where date between @start and  @end                              
        )m 
    )tab order by tab.date2

 SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
'select * from (
    select sum(bb.value) as value, bb.date as date, c.name as Name from bus_best bb
        join pro p on p.id = bb.id
        join con c on c.id = p.id
        join bus_t bu on bu.id = c.id
        where bb.date between '''+  cast     (@start as VARCHAR(50))+''' and '''+  cast     (@end as VARCHAR(50))+''' 
        and bu.name = '''+  cast     (@business as VARCHAR(50))+'''
        group by bb.date, c.name        
            ) as t

            PIVOT(SUM(t.value) 
          FOR date IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

            EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

and the output is something like:

```
Name   Jan    Feb    March   April  May   June  July ....
----------------------------------------------------------    
Name1  32     654    1        42    342   4     4543
Name2  54      3    234       43    453   432    22 
Name3  55      12   56       1234   43    643    12
Name4  77     235   3566    35635   23    2    3462
```

All I want is to add at bottom the last row which will sum all rows something like:

```
Name   Jan    Feb    March   April  May   June  July ....
----------------------------------------------------------    
Name1  32     654    1        42    342   4     4543
Name2  54      3    234       43    453   432    22 
Name3  55      12   56       1234   43    643    12
Name4  77     235   3566    35635   23    2    3462
Total ...     ....  ....    ....   ....   ....  .....
```

Comment: Union a new column name with sum of each column. you need to use a temp table for this

Comment: Get your dynamic query to write to a temp table.  Select from the temp table, union another query that does the summing.  Of course, this would probably be much easier (cleaner, and more efficient) in the application code.

Comment: This should be done by a reporting tool, not in SQL. All reporting tools allow adding group headers/footers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `GROUPING SETS`, you can add your total rows to your subquery, as a simple example if you have a query:

```
SELECT  A, B, SUM(C) AS C
FROM    T
GROUP BY A, B;
```

That gives you:

```
A       B       C
-------------------
1       1       5
1       2       3
2       1       8
2       2       1
```

If you use grouping sets as follows

```
SELECT  A, B, SUM(C) AS C
FROM    T
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((A, B), (A));
```

You get

```
A       B       C
-------------------
1       1       5
1       2       3
1       NULL    8   -- Total for A = 1
2       1       8
2       2       1
2       NULL    9   -- Total for A = 2
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT  A, B, SUM(C) AS C
FROM    T
GROUP BY A, B
UNION ALL
SELECT  A, NULL, SUM(C) AS C
FROM    T
GROUP BY A;
```

So each Grouping set essentially represents a further query, but internally SQL Server is able to re-use the aggregates, so is more efficient. All you need to do then is replace the `NULL` values for `Total`, and you have your total row(s).

I would also [advise against variable concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/1048425) (`SELECT @Columnname = @ColumnName + SomeField FROM SomeTable`) since the results are not guaranteeed to be correct. Instead use [XML extensions to concatenate your rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381512/what-this-query-does-to-create-comma-delimited-list-sql-server/10381975#10381975).

In addition, I would use a parameterised query, so rather than:

```
DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(10) = 'TEST';
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 'SELECT * FROM T WHERE Column = ''' + @Variable + '''';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery;
```

Instead use:

```
DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(10) = 'TEST';
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 'SELECT * FROM T WHERE Column = @Param';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery, N'@Param VARCHAR(10)', @Param = @Variable;
```

This gives you properly typed parameters, so there is no need to convert your dates to varchars to add them to your query, only for your query to have to convert them back to dates when it executes.

Finally, I haven't corrected this, but I would reccomend agaainst using `BETWEEN` when working with dates, the reasons for this are summed up nicely in the following articles:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Which gives you a final query of:   '

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @start AS DATETIME
DECLARE @end AS DATETIME
DECLARE @business AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @start = '2015-01-01';
SET @end   = '2015-12-01';
SET @business = 'EUR';

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
-- Uses "DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0)" to get the first of each
-- month then converts this to the format "yyyymmdd" (this is culture insensitive)
SET @ColumnName = 
        STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), D.[Date], 112))
                FROM (  SELECT  [Date] = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0)
                        FROM    bus_best
                        WHERE   [Date] BETWEEN @start AND @end
                        GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0)
                    ) AS d
                ORDER BY d.[Date]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
    'SELECT Name, ' +  @ColumnName + '
    FROM    (   SELECT  SUM(bb.value) AS Value, 
                        Date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, bb.date), 0), 
                        ISNULL(c.name, ''Total'') AS Name 
                FROM    bus_best bb
                        INNER JOIN pro AS p ON p.id = bb.id
                        INNER JOIN con AS c ON c.id = p.id
                        INNER JOIN bus_t AS bu ON bu.id = c.id
                WHERE   bb.date BETWEEN @StartParam AND @EndParam
                AND     bu.name = @BusinessParam
                GROUP BY GROUPING SETS 
                        (   (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, bb.date), 0), c.name), 
                            (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, bb.date), 0))
                        )
            ) AS t
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(t.value) 
                FOR date IN (' + @ColumnName + ')
            ) AS PVTTable;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    @DynamicPivotQuery, 
    N'@StartParam DATETIME, @EndParam DATETIME, @BusinessParam VARCHAR(50)',
    @StartParam = @Start,
    @EndParam = @End,
    @BusinessParam = @Business;
```

*N.B. I have not tested this fully, since it would require creating 4 tables which I can only guess at the data for, but there is hopefully enough information in the answer and the links to get you on the right track if there are some minor syntax errors*

**FULL WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T;

CREATE TABLE #T
(
    [Date] DATE,
    Business VARCHAR(50),
    Value INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT #T (Date, Business, Value, Name)
VALUES
    ('20150601', 'EUR', 1, 'Group 1'), 
    ('20150605', 'EUR', 12, 'Group 2'), 
    ('20150605', 'EUR', 3, 'Group 3'), 
    ('20150701', 'EUR', 2, 'Group 1'), 
    ('20150708', 'EUR', 2, 'Group 2'), 
    ('20150702', 'EUR', 7, 'Group 3'), 
    ('20150703', 'AAA', 2, 'Group 1');


DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @start AS DATETIME
DECLARE @end AS DATETIME
DECLARE @business AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @start = '2015-01-01';
SET @end   = '2015-12-01';
SET @business = 'EUR';

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SET @ColumnName = 
        STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), D.[Date], 120))
                FROM (  SELECT  [Date] = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0)
                        FROM    #T
                        WHERE   [Date] BETWEEN @start AND @end
                        GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0)
                    ) AS d
                ORDER BY d.[Date]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');


 SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
    'SELECT Name, ' +  @ColumnName + '
    FROM    (   SELECT  SUM(bb.value) AS Value, 
                        Date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, bb.date), 0), 
                        ISNULL(bb.name, ''Total'') AS Name 
                FROM    #T AS bb 
                WHERE   bb.date BETWEEN @StartParam AND @EndParam
                AND     bb.Business = @BusinessParam
                GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((bb.date, bb.name), (bb.Date))
            ) AS t
            PIVOT
            (   SUM(t.value) 
                FOR date IN (' + @ColumnName + ')
            ) AS PVTTable;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    @DynamicPivotQuery, 
    N'@StartParam DATETIME, @EndParam DATETIME, @BusinessParam VARCHAR(50)',
    @StartParam = @Start,
    @EndParam = @End,
    @BusinessParam = @Business;
```