# Search child rows for values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have something like this:

```
Transaction    Customer
1              Cust1
2              Cust2
3              Cust3
4              Cust4

TransID     Code
2           A
2           B
2           D
3           A
4           B
4           C
```

If I want to be able to do something like "IF Customer 'Cust1' Has code 'A'", how should I best build a view? I want to end up being able to query something like "Select Customer from View where Code in [Some list of codes]" OR "Select Cust1 from View Having Codes in [Some list of codes]"

While I can do something like

```
Customer       |   Codes 
Cust1          |   A, B, D 
Etc. 

SELECT Transaction from Tbl where Codes like 'A'
```

This seems to me to be an impractical way to do it.

Comment: Please share your expected result

Comment: @TheGameiswar That's the problem, I'm not sure what I should have. I could make something like 'TransID  | Code 1 | Code 2 | Code 3 ... ` but that seems impractical.

Comment: Well if you don't know what the expected results should be, how could we code something against it? what's the real problem you are trying to sove / answer here?

Comment: If you don't know what you want, how are we supposed to suggest something?

Comment: I tried to clarify. My end goal here is to make a view that I can easily query a certain way, I just can't figure how that particular view should look.

Comment: And what constitutes being "easily queryable in a certain way"? As written, it seems easily queryable. Unless you have some weird case where you need it in a certain format, what's wrong with leaving it as is?

Comment: I'll try to add more details.

Comment: Do you need the codes serialized? Or are you just doing that as a means to search the codes?

Comment: I'd suggest just doing `select TransId, Code from tbl o where exists (select 1 from tbl i where i.transid = o.transid and i.code = 'A')`

Comment: Sorry, I made a serious error in my data. There is a column in the first table that is NOT present in the second, and I want to match that column to certain records in the second table.  I'm sure that's at least part of the reason this question didn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it

```
;with xact_cust (xact, cust) as
(
    select 1, 'cust1' union all
    select 2, 'cust2' union all
    select 3, 'cust3' union all
    select 4, 'cust4' 
), xact_code (xact, code) as
(
    select 2, 'A' union all
    select 2, 'B' union all
    select 2, 'D' union all
    select 3, 'A' union all
    select 4, 'B' union all
    select 4, 'C' 
)
select Cust, Code
from xact_cust cust
inner join xact_code code
    on cust.xact = code.xact
where exists (select 1
              from xact_code i
              where i.xact = code.xact
                  and i.code = 'A')
```

If you NEED the codes serialized into a delimited list, take a look at this article: [What this query does to create comma delimited list SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381512/what-this-query-does-to-create-comma-delimited-list-sql-server)

Comment: Okay, this makes sense, it's exactly what I was failing to properly ask for, I'll just add a `group by cust` to get a single row for each one with the code I want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CustomerTransaction', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #CustomerTransaction;

CREATE TABLE #CustomerTransaction (
    TransactionID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Customer CHAR(5) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #CustomerTransaction (TransactionID, Customer) VALUES
    (1, 'Cust1'), (2, 'Cust2'), (3, 'Cust3'),
    (4, 'Cust4'), (5, 'Cust5');

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TransactionCode', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TransactionCode;

CREATE TABLE #TransactionCode (
    TransactionID INT NOT NULL,
    Code CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TransactionCode (TransactionID, Code) VALUES
    (2, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (2, 'D'), (3, 'A'), (4, 'B'), (4, 'C');

--SELECT * FROM #CustomerTransaction ct;
--SELECT * FROM #TransactionCode tc;
--=============================================================

SELECT 
    ct.TransactionID,
    ct.Customer,
    CodeList = STUFF(tcx.CodeList, 1, 1, '')
FROM 
    #CustomerTransaction ct
    CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT 
                    ', ' + tc.Code
                FROM 
                    #TransactionCode tc
                WHERE 
                    ct.TransactionID = tc.TransactionID
                ORDER BY
                    tc.Code ASC
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ) tcx (CodeList);
```

Results...

```
TransactionID Customer CodeList
------------- -------- -----------
1             Cust1    NULL
2             Cust2     A, B, D
3             Cust3     A
4             Cust4     B, C
5             Cust5    NULL
```

Comment: Would I need to use the like operator to query these results further?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg - No. You's want to do any additional filtering by adding a WHERE clause to the outer query to filter transactions or customers... or add to the existing WHERE in the sub-query to filter codes.