# SQL Query - Display Count & All ID's With Same Name

Tags: sql, database-design, sqlite

I'm trying to display the amount of table entries with the same name and the unique ID's associated with each of those entries.

So I have a table like so...

```
Table Names
------------------------------
ID    Name
0    John
1    Mike
2    John
3    Mike
4    Adam
5    Mike
```

I would like the output to be something like:

```
Name | Count | IDs
---------------------
Mike     3     1,3,5
John     2     0,2
Adam     1     4
```

I have the following query which does this except display all the unique ID's:

```
select name, count(*) as ct from names group by name order by ct desc;
```

Comment: It makes a big differnce in the code which database backend you are using, the solutions for this are client-specific.

Comment: yet another reason `write once run anywhere` SQL is a pipe dream! @Mike, you need to specify which database you need this for, there is no method that will work in all databases.

Answer (score 3):

```
select name,
       count(id) as ct, 
       group_concat(id) as IDs
from names
group by name
order by ct desc;
```

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for that

Comment: That will not work in SQL Server, but I think it will in mySQL

Comment: [`group_concat()` works for SQLite, too](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on version of MSSQL you are using (2005+), you can use the `FOR XML PATH` option.

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    COUNT(*) AS ct, 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(ID AS varchar(MAX)) 
           FROM names i 
           WHERE i.Name = n.Name FOR XML PATH(''))
        , 1, 1, '') as IDs
FROM names n
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY ct DESC
```

Closest thing to `group_concat` you'll get on MSSQL unless you use the SQLCLR option (which I have no experience doing). The `STUFF` function takes care of the leading comma. Also, you don't want to alias the inner `SELECT` as it will wrap the element you're selecting in an XML element (alias of `TD` causes each element to return as `<TD>value</TD>`).

Given the input above, here's the result I get:

```
Name    ct  IDs
Mike    3   1,3,5
John    2   0,2
Adam    1   4
```

### EDIT: DISCLAIMER

This technique will not work as intended for string fields that could possibly contain special characters (like ampersands `&`, less than `<`, greater than `>`, and any number of other formatting characters). As such, this technique is most beneficial for simple integer values, although can still be used for text if you are **ABSOLUTELY SURE** there are no special characters that would need to be escaped. As such, read the solution posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5031297/65223) to ensure these characters get properly escaped.

Comment: your answer will not properly handle XML characters like: `<` or `&` or `>`.  For the proper way to do XML concatenation in SQL Server 2005+ go here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5031297/65223

Comment: For simple ID's (which is what he's looking for) this is fine, although I agree you have to be careful with this technique.

Comment: @SPFiredrake, this answer will be a big fail for the poor guy that reaches this page in the future and tries to concatenate the special characters.  The same will happen when the OP tries to reuse this method and they start getting `&amp;` and `&gt;` sprinkled within their result set.

Comment: Added a disclaimer. However, there are answers with a lot more traffic that would come up well before this answer would that include the fix, so I'm not too worried about it being a big bowl of fail. Honestly, I like to leave my solutions as simple as possible and let the copy/pasta army just trip over themselves when they realize it doesn't apply to every situation. Hell, even I trip myself up every once in a while with this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another SQL Server method, using recursive CTE:

Link to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fe79/1)

```
; with MyCTE(name,ids, name_id, seq)
as(
    select name, CAST( '' AS VARCHAR(8000) ), -1, 0
    from Data
    group by name
    union all
    select d.name,  
            CAST( ids + CASE WHEN seq = 0 THEN '' ELSE ', ' END + cast(id as varchar) AS VARCHAR(8000) ),
            CAST( id AS int),
            seq + 1
    from MyCTE cte 
    join Data d
        on cte.name = d.name
    where d.id > cte.name_id
)
SELECT name, ids
      FROM ( SELECT name, ids,
                    RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY seq DESC )
               FROM MyCTE ) D ( name, ids, rank )
     WHERE rank = 1
```