# Comma-delimited Distinct Values Of A Table Or Result-set

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

So I have specification tables that relate to products that vary by product type. I need a stored procedure that will return a single-row of unique comma-delimited values in each of the columns (used for site navigation code) in a spec table (or a resultset of said spec table).

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you all for the responses so far. I will explain in more detail...

Each spec table has a different number of columns (and rows, for that matter). Let's say one of them has 50,000 rows and a manufacturer column. Now let's assume there are 5 unique manufacturers in the there as well. Let's also assume the same table also has a color column that shares 7 colors among all 50,000 rows.

My (currently imaginary) stored procedure should return one row with the following columns...

- **Manufacturer**: 
  Manu1,Manu2,Manu3,Manu4,Manu5
- **Color**: 
  color1,color2,color3,color4,color5,color6,color7

I intend to use this result to build my site navigation.

Comment: just somewhat brief... any mor detail?

Comment: Something like SELECT a1 + ',' a2, COUNT(*) FROM Tab1 GROUP BY a1, a2

Comment: Just add columns and concats as required and add an appropriate predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood:

```
declare @productTypes table (Id int, Name nvarchar(32))
declare @products table (Id bigint not null identity(1,1), ProductType int, ProductName nvarchar(32))

insert @productTypes (Id, Name)
select 1, 'Food'
union
select 2, 'Drink'

insert @products (ProductType, ProductName)
select 1, 'Chips'
union
select 1, 'Fish'
union
select 2, 'Guinness'
union
select 2, 'Water'
union
select 2, 'Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster'

select pt.Name 
, STUFF
(
    (
        Select ',' + a.ProductName
        from @products a
        where a.ProductType = pt.Id
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''
) ProductsOfType
from @productTypes pt
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e80ff/1

Results:

```
Name    ProductsOfType
Food    Chips,Fish
Drink   Guinness,Pan Galactic Gargle Blaster,Water
```

Comment: Can you give any insight on the performance of this solution?

Comment: Also, another thought... What if the code doesn't know exactly what columns its dealing with? Is there an equally-elegant way to handle a situation like that?

Comment: @m-albert : Not sure on performance for large amounts of data; it's better to use a CLR function if you're concerned about that.  That said, there's another post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings, which details performant aggregate string concatenation.

Comment: @M-albert if you didn't know the column names you could potentially use dynamic SQL (i.e. build up the SQL in an `nvarchar(max)` variable, then run with `exec(@sql)`; though dynamic SQL's not allowed within stored procedures, so wouldn't be valid for your original question

Comment: ps. similar questions/answers via this one, should you be interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings

Comment: Dynamic SQL works just fine in stored procs (I am using it now). I think you mean UDF's. :)