# Return Multiple Rows in One Cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I've looked around and seen the XML trick and the Variable trick, and neither really made enough sense to me to implement. What I have is a table with 4 Columns, The first is a unique identifier, the second is a relation to a different table, the third is varbinary(max), the last is a string. I want to combine columns three and four over column two. Is this possible?

Example of Data:

```
| FileId  |  UniqueI1  |  BinaryData  | FileName |
|---------+------------+--------------+----------|
|   1     |     1      |    <byte>    | asp.jpg  |
|   2     |     1      |    <byte>    | asp1.jpg |
|   3     |     2      |    <byte>    | asp2.jpg |
|   4     |     2      |    <byte>    | asp3.jpg |
|   5     |     2      |    <byte>    | asp4.jpg |
```

Preferred Output:

```
|  UniqueI1  |          BinaryData          |          FileName            |
|------------+------------------------------+------------------------------|
|     1      |    <byte>, <byte>            | asp.jpg, asp1.jpg            |
|     2      |    <byte>, <byte>, <byte>    | asp2.jpg, asp3.jpg, asp4.jpg |
```

I appreciate any help you may be able to provide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to group your data and aggregate the BinaryData and FileName columns by concatenating their values.

There are no built-in aggregates for concatenation in t-sql, but there are a couple of ways to reach the same results.

In my opinion, by far the easiest way is to write a custom aggregate in c# leveraging the CLR. But it can also be done using STUFF or XML. You should have a look at [Does T-SQL have an aggregate function to concatenate strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      FileID INT ,
      UniqueID INT ,
      Data VARBINARY(100) ,
      FileName VARCHAR(10)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 1, 'asp.jpg' ),
        ( 2, 1, 2, 'asp1.jpg' ),
        ( 3, 2, 3, 'asp2.jpg' ),
        ( 4, 2, 4, 'asp3.jpg' ),
        ( 5, 2, 5, 'asp4.jpg' )


SELECT  UniqueID ,
        MAX(ca.data) AS Data,
        MAX(ca.name) AS Name
FROM    @t t1
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    STUFF(
                   (SELECT  ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), t2.Data, 2)
                    FROM    @t t2
                    WHERE   t1.UniqueID = t2.UniqueID
                    ORDER BY FileID                  
                                FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                                          TYPE
                   ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS DATA ,
                                STUFF(
                   (SELECT  ', ' + t2.FileName
                    FROM    @t t2
                    WHERE   t1.UniqueID = t2.UniqueID
                    ORDER BY FileID                  
                                FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                                          TYPE
                   ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS NAME
                    ) ca
GROUP BY UniqueID
```

Output:

```
UniqueID    Data                            Name
1           00000001, 00000002              asp.jpg, asp1.jpg
2           00000003, 00000004, 00000005    asp2.jpg, asp3.jpg, asp4.jpg
```

For pivoting:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY FileID ) AS rn
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  c.UniqueID ,
            ca1.[1] AS Data1 ,
            ca1.[2] AS Data2 ,
            ca1.[3] AS Data3 ,
            ca2.[1] AS File1 ,
            ca2.[2] AS File2 ,
            ca2.[3] AS File3
    FROM    cte c
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    *
                          FROM      ( SELECT    UniqueID ,
                                                rn ,
                                                Data
                                      FROM      cte ci
                                      WHERE     ci.UniqueID = c.UniqueID
                                    ) t PIVOT( MAX(Data) FOR rn IN ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) p
                        ) ca1    
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    *
                          FROM      ( SELECT    UniqueID ,
                                                rn ,
                                                FileName
                                      FROM      cte ci
                                      WHERE     ci.UniqueID = c.UniqueID
                                    ) t PIVOT( MAX(FileName) FOR rn IN ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) p
                        ) ca2
    GROUP BY c.UniqueID, ca1.[1], ca1.[2], ca1.[3], ca2.[1], ca2.[2], ca2.[3]
```

Output:

```
UniqueID    Data1       Data2       Data3       File1     File2     File3
1           0x00000001  0x00000002  NULL        asp.jpg   asp1.jpg  NULL
2           0x00000003  0x00000004  0x00000005  asp2.jpg  asp3.jpg  asp4.jpg
```

You can change this to dynamic query if you don't want to manually add additional files.

Comment: While this most certainly does work, the problem is that I still need the data in byte form for my web application. I am using a telerik radgrid and I just wanted all the files to be in the same row as the Parent record it's attached to, as opposed to populating a record for each individual file. My users need to be able to click the document name and be able to open/download the file... Perhaps I should move this over to questions about radgrid data population instead.

Comment: Ok, you want pivoting.