# Check if all ID's in a Column have a specific value in another column, different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, exists

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
Id 
1232
1344
1313
4242
3242
555
```

Table 2:

```
Id    sym    mnth  code
1232    9      1     32
1344    15     1     14
1313    10     1     32
4242    11     1     32
3242    9      1     32
1232    9      2     32
1344    13     2     14
1313    9      2     32
4242    10     2     32
3242    9      2     32
```

I want to check if all the id's in table 1 have the value 9 in sym for all the month (1,2 in the example) but only for those id's which for them the code in table 2 is '32'.

If not return me the id and the months for which the 9 is missing separate by a comma. If Id in table 1 doesn't exists at all in table 2 return null in the month column and the id.

The output in the example should be:

```
ID    month
1313    1
4242    1,2
555    NULL

1344 doesn't exist because the code column for hime is not 32.
```

I started writing this:

```
SELECT table1.id
FROM table1
WHERE not EXISTS (SELECT id FROM table2 
                  WHERE table2.sml = '9' AND table2.code = 32)
```

But I really don't know how to make the query run for all month and plug the results like I've mentioned in the output. Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: add table1.id = table2.id to the sub-query's where clause?

Comment: Sorry,didn't understand.

Comment: Think you'll probably need an `OUTER APPLY` and, for the output of `month` that you're after, you'll also need a custom aggregate function.

Comment: You did not reference table1 anywhere in your EXISTS() subquery, so it will return the same results for every row in table1, instead of results that are related to each row specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Here I create a cte to find out what are the month missing.
- Has to create a derivated table `months` to include all the months.
- Then perform a left join, so either didnt exist one item in table 2 to match or the item was the wrong one
- Once I have all the wrong link create the string using `XML PATH`

  - [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b24e8/4)

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT t1.*, t2.sym, t2.mnth, t2.code
    FROM Table1 t1
    CROSS JOIN (select 1 month_id union select 2) months    
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
      ON t2.[id] = t1.id
     AND t2.[mnth] = months.month_id
    WHERE  ([code] = 32 OR [code] is NULL)
      AND  ([sym] <> 9 OR [sym] is NULL)

), MAIN as (
    SELECT DISTINCT c2.Id, (SELECT c1.mnth + ',' as [text()]
                            FROM cte c1
                            WHERE c1.Id = c2.Id
                            ORDER BY c1.Id
                            For XML PATH ('')
                ) [months]
    FROM cte c2
)
SELECT Id,
       IIF( len([months]) > 0, 
            LEFT ([months], len([months])-1),
            NULL) as [months]
FROM Main
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|   Id | months |
|------|--------|
|  555 | (null) |
| 1313 |      1 |
| 4242 |    1,2 |
```

Comment: Hey, the code did not work for me but I tried other solution because I ran out of time to continue with this idea for display. Thank you for all the answers. You were very helpful.

Comment: Sorry if didnt work, but I think I solve the question you make here. Maybe later you can try and make a new question with additional information.

Comment: @Jordan1200 Why was my answer, also, previously accepted and unaccepted?  Especially considering mine is fully correct, and this, as it stands, is not.  [See SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a2cc/2)

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of conditions in your request that don't compliment each other so well, so the query is likely going to look a bit messy, and probably perform slow.  You'll need a way to combine results into your comma-delimited list.  SQL Server doesn't have a built-in string concatenation aggregate function, so you'll need to work on something [similar to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings) in order to get the `month` output you are after.

What I've come up with that gives you the results you are after is:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.[month]
FROM Table1 t1
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT stuff((SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar, mnth)
                FROM Table2
                WHERE id = t1.id and sym <> 9 and code = 32
                ORDER BY mnth ASC
                for xml path('')
               ),1,2,'') as [month]
) t2
WHERE
    id in (SELECT id FROM Table2 WHERE sym <> 9 and code = 32)
or  id not in (SELECT id FROM Table2);
```

Note that I added the `ORDER BY mnth ASC` line so that the result `month` field has the non-9-sym months in logical order.  If you'd rather see the order they appear in the table, just remove this line.

**Edit:** Removed the initial "thinking out loud" answer and left just the actual solution to prevent confusion.

Comment: Thank's mike. Any way to generlize it to more than two month? 
when I add '3,4,5,..' it gives me an error.

Comment: @Jordan1200 I'm actually not that familiar with the `stuff` function, as seeing it in that other question was the first time I've come across it.  I can experiment with tweaking the query some more.  Does the accepted answer provided by Juan give you correct output in all cases?  If so, I may just delete my answer, as it's ultimately misleading if it doesn't handle more than 2.

Comment: @Jordan1200 On the contrary... When I add months 3, 4, 5 and run I find that my solution continues to work, yet the accepted answer only shows "1, 2".  I don't see an error in either case.  What are you seeing?  Note, I did find something in my answer that it doesn't show the months in order if they are not in order in the table, so I'm updating my answer to include ordered results.

Comment: Dont know why OP didnt report the error in my question. Didnt know about   the error for more than 2 months

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from
  (select 
        id,
        stuff((select ', ' + convert(varchar, month_)
               from tbl2 t2 
               where t1.id = t2.id 
               and t2.sym != 9 and t2.code != 32
               for xml path('')),1,2,'') month_
    from tbl1 t1
    group by id 

UNION

select t1.id, convert(varchar, t2.month_)
               from tbl1 t1
                JOIN tbl2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
               and t2.sym = 9 and t2.code = 32) as t

where t.month_ is not null
```