# How to list the results from a SELECT statement into a column of another SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

(I'm quite sure this question is answered here somewhere, but I'm not finding it, nor being able to put together the terms for a good search. So I'm sorry in advance if this question is duplicate.)

Here's my problem:

If I have a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT a.Id, b.Id
FROM TableA as a
JOIN TableB as b on a.Id = b.Id
```

And I get a result like this:

```
+-----+------+
|a.Id | b.Id |
|  1  |  1   |
|  1  |  2   |
|  2  |  1   |
|  2  |  3   |
|  2  |  4   |
|  3  |  3   |
+-----+------+
```

I would like to know how can I approach the problem of having to get this:

```
+-----+----------+
|a.Id | b.Id     |
|  1  |  1, 2    |
|  2  |  1, 3, 4 |
|  3  |  3       |
+-----+----------+
```

Further info / Edit: I'm using MSSQL. And yes, this question is duplicated:
([Does T-SQL have an aggregate function to concatenate strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings))

Comment: what sql server are you using?  MySQL, MSSQL, Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can use  group_concat

```
SELECT a.Id, group_concat(b.Id)
FROM TableA as a
JOIN TableB as b on a.Id = b.Id
group by a.id;
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for the suggestion. I'm using MSSQL but I'll look for something similar