# How do I join with a table function result in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, join

I have something like these 2 tables (but millions of rows in real):

```
items:
| X | Y |
---------
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
---------

details:
| X | A | B |
-------------
| 1 | a | b |
| 1 | c | d |
| 3 | e | f |
| 3 | g | h |
-------------
```

I have to aggregate several rows of one table `details` for one row in another table `items` to show them in a GridView like this:

```
| items.X | items.Y | details.A | details.B |
---------------------------------------------
| 1       | 2       | a, c      | b, d      |
| 3       | 4       | e, g      | f, h      |
---------------------------------------------
```

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5031204/5823275) and the related questions and I know about [GROUP_CONCAT](https://groupconcat.codeplex.com/), but I am not allowed to install it on the customer system. Because I don't have a chance to do this natively, I created a stored function (which I'm allowed to create), which returns a table with the columns `X`, `A` and `B`. This function works fine so far, but I don't seem to get these columns added to my result set.

Currently I'm trying to join the function result with a query on `items`, join-criterion would be the `X`-column in the example above. I made a minimal example with the AdventureWorks2012 database, which contains a table function `dbo.ufnGetContactInformation(@PersonID INT)` to join with the `[Person].[EmailAddress]` table on `BusinessEntityID`:

```
SELECT
    [EmailAddress]
    -- , p.[FirstName]
    -- , p.[LastName]
FROM
    [Person].[EmailAddress] e
INNER JOIN
    dbo.ufnGetContactInformation(e.[BusinessEntityID]) p
    ON p.[PersonID] = e.[BusinessEntityID]
```

The 2 commented lines indicate, what I try to do in reality, but if not commented, they hide the actual error I get:

```
Event 4104, Level 16, Status 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier 'e.BusinessEntityID' could not be bound.
```

I understand, that during the joining process there is no value for `e.[BusinessEntityID]` yet. So I cannot select a specific subset in the function by using the function parameters, this should be in the join criteria anyway. Additionally I cannot have the function return *all* rows or create a temporary table, because this is insanely slow and expensive regarding both time and space in my specific situation.

*Is there another way to achieve something like this with 2 existing tables and a table function?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Apply

Cross apply is similar to inner join,Outer apply is similar to left join

```
SELECT
    [EmailAddress]
    -- , p.[FirstName]
    -- , p.[LastName]
FROM
    [Person].[EmailAddress] e
cross apply
    dbo.ufnGetContactInformation(e.[BusinessEntityID]) p
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.