# Concatenate strings from subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't know how to concatenate string from subquery. Please note - my inner query is much more complicated. I've omitted long WHERE conditions to make things more simple - I need to select from outer query.
And here is the problem - I've managed to select from all columns except from MEEV_NTO - I need to concatenate strings from this query and separate them with commas.

Please note - I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings) - but it selects from table, not from subquery.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MERC_KEY, MEEV_QUA_SUM, MEEV_NTO
FROM
(
    SELECT MERC_KEY, SUM(MEEV_QUA) OVER(PARTITION BY MERC_KEY) MEEV_QUA_SUM, MEEV_NTO FROM @tbl1
) A
```

Desired output:

```
+----------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| MERC_KEY | MEEV_QUA_SUM |             MEEV_NTO              |
+----------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
|        1 |           14 | FIRST TEST,SECOND TEST,THIRD TEST |
|        2 |            6 | ANOTHER, AND ANOTHER              |
+----------+--------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Whole example:

```
declare @tbl1 table
(
    MERC_KEY INT,   
    MEEV_QUA INT,
    MEEV_NTO VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT @tbl1 (MERC_KEY, MEEV_QUA, MEEV_NTO)
VALUES(1, 4, 'FIRST TEST'),
(1, 3, 'SECOND TEST'),
(1, 7, 'THIRD TEST'),
(2, 2, 'ANOTHER'),
(2, 4, 'AND ANOTHER')
```

Comment: This is one of the very few things MySql does better (`group_concat()` would make this much easier).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn very being the key word here :-). SQL Server jumped on the wagon fashionably late only in it's 2017 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2017 or later, you may use `STRING_AGG` here:

```
SELECT
    MERC_KEY,
    SUM(MEEV_QUA) AS MEEV_QUA_SUM,
    STRING_AGG(MEEV_NTO, ',') MEEV_NTO
FROM @tbl1
GROUP BY
    MERC_KEY;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate functions for sub-query just like for tables. But in this case, you can use it for @tbl1, the query should look like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MERC_KEY, MEEV_QUA_SUM, MEEV_NTO
FROM
(
    SELECT MERC_KEY, SUM(MEEV_QUA) OVER(PARTITION BY MERC_KEY) MEEV_QUA_SUM, STRING_AGG(MEEV_NTO,',') AS MEEV_NTO FROM @tbl1 GROUP BY MERC_KEY
) A
```

You told that your sub-query is much more complicated so I keep your query structure.