# Assign values to variables in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms-2017

```
 select  @numOfColumns =  count(distinct Col) from #b
 SET @sql2=
'SELECT'+ @columns +'+= QUOTENAME(Col) + '',''
 from (SELECT DISTINCT top @numOfColumns Col FROM #b ORDER BY Col) A';

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql2;
```

I am trying to get this stored procedure to work. Trying to pass @numOfColumns to the statement then assign the values from  QUOTENAME(Col) to @columns and Then Exec the statement.

Script

```
DECLARE 
@columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
@sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
 @sql2     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
@numOfColumns int = 0;

SELECT customerid, curbal,  Col = CAST (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
convert(int,customerid) ORDER BY convert(float,curbal) desc) as int)
into #b
FROM [sav acc]

select  @numOfColumns =  count(distinct Col) from #b

SET @sql2= 'SELECT '+ @columns+' += QUOTENAME(Col) + '','' from (SELECT 
DISTINCT top (@numOfColumns) Col FROM #b ORDER BY Col) A';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql2, N'@numOfColumns', @numOfColumns int;
```

This is origin of post. [ORIGINAL POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331041/how-to-pivot-without-knowing-fixed-columns-in-t-sql)  . The solution did work, But i tested it with the Source data it would positions column at [3], [2], [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331041/how-to-pivot-without-knowing-fixed-columns-in-t-sql) and and I wanted the columns as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331041/how-to-pivot-without-knowing-fixed-columns-in-t-sql),[2],[3]

Comment: `@numOfColumns` should be appended to the string. Not in it

Comment: Now getting error after adjustment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT+= QUOTENAME(Col) + ','
from (SELECT DISTINCT top ' to data type int.

Comment: @JamesS no, it should be parametrised, not injected. It's a parameter, not a dynamic object.

Comment: Why the dynamic sql? I don't see anything this code that indicates you need to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the way you are using `TOP` is pointless. If you have 5 distinct values for `Col` in `#b` then `SELECT DISTINCT Col FROM #b` will only return 5 records, regardless of if you apply `TOP 5` or not. It seems you are only using it to allow sorting, but you could just put the sort in the outer query.

Secondly, you should not use variable assignment to concatenate strings, [the behaviour is unreliable and undocumented](https://marc.durdin.net/2015/07/concatenating-strings-in-sql-server-or-undefined-behaviour-by-design/) you should use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), or for earlier versions of SQL Server you can [leverage the `XML` extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5031297/1048425), either:

```
CREATE TABLE #B (Col CHAR(1));
INSERT #B (Col) VALUES ('A'), ('A'), ('B'), ('C');

DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    (   SELECT  STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(Col), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Col)
        FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Col FROM #B) AS b
    );
```

Or

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        STUFF(( SELECT  CONCAT(',', QUOTENAME(Col))
                FROM    #B
                GROUP BY Col
                ORDER BY Col
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
```

While the above shows that dynamic sql is unnecessary, it would also be unnecessary if you were using `@top`, you could simply use:

```
DECLARE  @numOfColumns INT = (SELECT count(distinct Col) from #b);
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT  @Columns += QUOTENAME(Col) + ','
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@numOfColumns) Col FROM #B) AS b
ORDER BY Col;

SELECT @Columns;
```

Comment: As simple as it seems, with the original source, the source data produced different outcome upon execution.  When i run code on source data, this part: SELECT  @Columns += QUOTENAME(Col) + ',' : stores column as [3], [1], [2]. But in original post, The solution given to me would position them correctly [1], [2], [3].  But This works. Thank you.