# How to convert row to column in my case using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I need to convert a row to a column, I never worked on in this scenario.

**Product**

```
 ProdID   Price
 ---------------
 111      52.5
 111      50.5
 112      40
 111      65
```

**Expected results:**

```
ProdID    Price1    Price2    Price3
------------------------------------
111       52.5      50.5     65
112       40
```

**Note**

I have no idea how many prices will be there for the same item. Sometimes it will be only one, sometimes 2 or 5.

So based on that it has to create the column.

I saw a lot of posts only converting the exact column, not for a dynamic column like my scenario.

Comment: You'll need a dynamic SQL query similar to that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: @Nick In my case, the column name will be `Price1, Price2, Price3`. Not static column

Comment: You could get close with `GROUP_CONCAT`. For example: `SELECT ProdID, Prices AS GROUP_CONCAT(Price, ',') FROM Product GROUP BY ProdID`

Comment: @AjahnCharles I search about `GROUP_CONCAT`. I don't want like that. Your result will show in single column. But this is good thing that I learn about `Group_concat` Thanks

Comment: @Liamneesan `GROUP_CONCAT` is MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: I've just given [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60370238/9071943), please take a look at @Nick

Comment: The SQL language has a _very strict rule:_ know the number and data type for the columns at query build time, _before_ looking at any data. Even `SELECT *` queries meet this rule because column list described by `*` is known and static. What you're asking for now _breaks the rule._ The best option usually pivots in the client, but if you _realy_ must, you need three steps: **1)** Run a query to look at the data tell you how many columns you'll need. **2)** Use those results to a build a new query on the fly, which a separate entry for each column from step 1. **3)** Run the query from step 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9131f5a108f9be81726c054cf9ee9ecb)

1. You need to use `Dynamic SQL PIVOT` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/60331153
2. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` combines with `CONCAT()` to mark dynamic column like `Price1, Price2, Price3, etc.`

```
    DECLARE 
        @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';


     SELECT ProdID, Price, Col = CONCAT('Price', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProdID ORDER BY ProdID))
     into #b
     FROM #a

    SELECT @columns += QUOTENAME(Col) + ','
    from (SELECT DISTINCT Col FROM #b) A

    -- remove the last comma
    SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);


    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ProdID, Price, Col FROM  #b) src PIVOT( MAX([Price]) FOR Col IN ('+ @columns +')) AS pivot_table;';

    -- execute the dynamic SQL
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You should be voting to close as a duplicate for something which is basically identical.

Comment: I do think so. But the `PARTITION BY ProdID ORDER BY ProdID` has a little different. So I still want to give the answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Create table ItemDetails
(
    prodid numeric(10),
    price numeric(10,2),
    orderno int identity(1,1)
)
```

---

```
declare @pricecols varchar(max)='',
@pricecolName nvarchar(max)='',
@statement nvarchar(4000)=''

 select @pricecolName= stuff( 
            (
                select ','+pricecol from (
             select  distinct 'price'+convert(varchar(10),(row_number() over(partition by prodid order by orderno))) 
            pricecol FROM ItemDetails   ) as tbl
            for xml path('')),1,1,'')


set @statement= 'select prodID,'+@pricecolName+' from (
    select  prodid,price,''price''+convert(varchar(10),(row_number() 
    over(partition by prodid order by orderno))) as
            pricecol FROM ItemDetails  
) [itemPrice]
pivot
(
    max(price)
    for pricecol
    in ('+@pricecolName+') ) as pivatetble'

 exec sp_executesql  @statement
```

---

[OutPut- (note: price value duplicated for Item2 [112])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySbWM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySbWM.png)